# How to break a line in a table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)

In a table I would like to have a line break in the text inside a cell. Is there an easy way to do so, or do I have to create a new line without borders? The same holds true for other situations such as breaking a line in a caption for instance.

Comment: It took me a while to understand the problem, it might be worth stating that simply using a \\ in the text created a new line for all columns and this (presumably) is what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: You can also use a minipage inside your table (it's similar to a parbox).

Comment: @Yossi: exactly, using \\ acts weird in a table, and has no effect in a caption. I think there are many cases where you can't use \\ but stil would like to break line. In a figure / box e.g.

Comment: See also [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell/11555).

Comment: You might want to use [varwidth](https://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) which provides a minipage with variable width (e,g, just as much width as needed for the content) in which you can break lines

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Would a `\parbox` work?

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
one line& \parbox[t]{5cm}{another\\column}\\
second line here& and here
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make parbox tight and omitting the width parameter somehow? And how to make it centered?

Comment: @nimcap: better to start a new question than put it here...What do you mean by tight? a table is flexible and its width depends on the width of its contents? center by centering the column of the table (using c) and centering the parbox, using \begin{center}....

Comment: @YossiFarjoun: I started a new question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38924/newline-in-a-table-cell-which-is-centered

Comment: @nimcap: and arn't you glad you did? ;-)

Answer (score 51):

`\newline` works in paragraph columns

Example:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
first line
\newline second line & still on first line \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 15):

Is this for a single cell, or an entire column of cells? If the later, try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lp{.2\textwidth}l}
        42 & A paragraph of text & 42\\
        42 & Another paragraph & 42
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Even if it is for a single cell, I suspect that this is still the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding line breaks in captions: if you use the `caption` package `\\` works. In the optional argument you should protect it. Here's a demonstration example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\bigskip
\begin{figure}[hb]
\centering Test
\caption[Short\protect\\text]{Test\\example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Because the `caption` package provides a lot of features regarding justification and customization I would not work without it. But if you really wish to avoid this package, it can also be done using `\parbox`. The optional positioning parameter `t` might be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\bigskip
\begin{figure}[hb]
\centering Test
\caption[Short\protect\\text]{\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{Just a Test\\example}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fine code! I had an awful error in the `subfigure` environment, but your idea of using ` \protect\\ ` instead of ` \\ ` has fixed it. (I had given ` \\ ` as a macro parameter and it did not work).

Answer (score 5):

```
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
    \pbox{20cm}{This is the first \\ cell} & second \\ \hline
    3rd & and the last cell \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. Generally, it would be great to add some explanation to code in answers. In this special case, the reader can find some words here: [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell/11555#11555).