# How to add a forced line break inside a table cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I have some text in a table and I want to add a forced line break. I want to insert a forced line break without having to specify the column width, i.e. something like the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Foo bar & Foo <forced line break here> bar & Foo bar \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I know that `\\` inserts a line break in most cases, but here it starts a new table row instead.

---

A similar question was asked before: [How to break a line in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-break-a-line-in-a-table)

Answer (score 726, accepted):

Use the [`makecell`](https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) package. This package provides commands for formatting cells, including `\thead` (for header cells) and `\makecell` (for regular cells). For instance, to create a cell containing line breaks:

```
\makecell{Some really \\ longer text}
```

Additionally, the horizontal and vertical alignments can be chosen independently from those of the table they're included in. The default is `cc`, but you can change it globally in the preamble with

```
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{vh}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{vh}
```

where `v` is one  of `t`, `c`, or `b` and `h` one of `l`, `c`, or `r`. Alternatively, for a single cell, you can use the `\makecell` or `\thead` commands with the optional argument `[vh]`.

---

Demo:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c |}
      \hline
      \thead{A Head} & \thead{A Second \\ Head} & \thead{A Third \\ Head} \\
      \hline
      Some text &  \makecell{Some really \\ longer text}  & Text text text  \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled MWE]

Comment: This is great, it works without specifying a width and does not need confusing hacks. Maybe worth to mention that the example here contains much more than is actually necessary to answer the question: just adding `\usepackage{makecell}` and using `\makecell{...\\...}` is sufficient to get a linebreak in the cell.

Comment: In contrast to `pbox`, this also works with `adjustbox` (`\adjustbox{valign=t}{\makecell{content}}`)

Comment: I get the following error:
`Missing number, treated as zero.`
`Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`
`pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file futr8r): Font futr8r at 604 not found`

Comment: @maja: This kind of message is related with the font. It means the compiler does not find  the type 1 font and tries to make a type 3 version, but doesn't know how to do it. Do you have the font (it is a commercial font, as far as I know)? Also, do you happen to have MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: @Bernard I use MikTex only for the initial toolchain installation and for the package management. The font problem might be caused by my universities custom LaTeX template, but I don't know enough about the language to resolve it. However, egreg's answer worked for me, so I'm using that now.

Comment: Is it me or the `\thead` command actually decreases the font size of the cell?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś, no it is not you. makecell defaults `thead` to `footnotesize`. If you want something else, you can redefine it globally or locally with, e.g. `\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}`.

Comment: How do you make the text left/right aligned? Thanks.

Comment: As explained, if it's for all you document, `\renewcommand{\cellalign}{l}` (it will remain vertically centred), or, for some specific cells, `makecell[l]{ ... }` or `\thead[l]{ ... }`.

Comment: I am afraid `\makecel{  ... \\ ... }` does not preserve vertical alignment

Comment: As explained, it is by default vertically and horizontally centred. But you can change that either redefining `\cellalign`  in the preamble, so it's valid for the whole document, or using an optional argument, such  as `\makecell[l] { ... \\ ... }` to have all lines left-aligned, for instance.

Comment: After searching for 30mins straight, finally an answer which doesn't add ugly hyphenation or spacing, has proper vertical space (less than between rows), doesn't mess up neighbour cells and allows proper alignment. Thank you!!!

Comment: If the text is too long, the table gets out of the document. Is it possible to use `\makecell` with the default automatic line break *and* custom line breaks to prevent the table having a greater width than the page?

Comment: @mhellmeier:  I don't think so. The aim of the package is to allow for manual line breaks in standard column specifiers (`l,r` or `c`). For automatic line breaks, you can use a nested tabular with a fixed width column.

Comment: `makecell` is old and not supported. `\thead` sometimes produces unexpected result. Nowadays just use `\parbox`, `\pbox`, or `\Block{1-1}` from `nicematrix`.

Comment: I have no special problems with `makecell`, except used with `colortbl`. Your solution requires determining at least an approximate cells width. I prefer `\Centerstack`,or `\Vectorstack`, from `stackengine`, when `makecell` doesn't work smoothly.

Comment: the second line segment in `\makecell{...\\...}` is aligned center w.r.t the first part.

Comment: @ManjoyDas: Yes, this is the default: it is vertically and horizontally centred. It can be changed either globally  with, e.g.  `renewcommand\cellalign}{lb}` to have all \makecell bibottom and left aligned. If you want it only for specific cells, use an optional argument: `\makecell[lb]{…}`.

Comment: Doesn't work when you specify the cell width such as p{2cm}.

Comment: @AlbertChen: But you don't need makecell in this case! Just insert a `\newline` command where you want a line break.

Comment: Somehow the makecell package doesn't coordinate well with the AASTEX documentclass.  This combination creates an ugly large horizontal spacing at the beginning of the cell.

Comment: @HD189733b: I think you should open a new question, with a (complete) short code illustrating the problem, so that we can play with it and try to understand what happens.

Comment: Interestingly, the compiler times out for me on Overleaf when I use \thead{text \\ [text]}, it does not seem to like newline before " [" or "[" so I had to add a dummy character on the second row.

Comment: @a20: That is normal since ``` \\ ``` can take an optional argument to add some vertical spacing. The simplest solution would be to add a pair of braces around the brackets, like this: ```\thead{text \\ {[text]}}\\```.

Answer (score 451):

It's a quite old question, but I'll add my answer anyway, as the method I suggest didn't appear in the others

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Foo bar & \begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}Foo\\bar\end{tabular} & Foo bar \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

where `x` is either `t`, `c`, or `b` to force the desired vertical alignment.

In case this is needed in more than a couple of places, it's better to define a command

```
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
```

so the table line before can be one of

```
Foo bar & \specialcell{Foo\\bar} & Foo bar \\    % vertically centered
Foo bar & \specialcell[t]{Foo\\bar} & Foo bar \\ % aligned with top rule
Foo bar & \specialcell[b]{Foo\\bar} & Foo bar \\ % aligned with bottom rule
```

More variations are possible, for instance specifying also the horizontal alignment in the special cell.

Notice the `@{}` to suppress added space before and after the cell text.

Comment: For those wanting to control the horizontal alignment, change c@ to l@ or r@ (or make it another parameter like the vertical alignment?).  Thanks egreg

Comment: @dolan I'd go with another parameter: `#1` vertical alignment (optional), `#2` horizontal alignment, `#3` text.

Comment: I had an issue with the text getting squished into the top of the cell. I went with a hack of adding `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}` (via array package) to the specialcell command. Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: @dolan Probably using `\strut#2\strut` is better. Use the `booktabs` package and this will be less of a concern.

Comment: `\parbox` will do the same, but you have set a width: `\parbox[t]{5cm}{foo\\bar}`

Comment: @Born2Smile There's the `varwidth` environment (package of the same name), but it's overkill.

Comment: A quick comparison to `multirow`: 1. Both lead to correct highlighting behavior in the pdf-file (if one selects text with the mouse, the multi-row cell is selected/highlighted first before any other material in the non-bottom lines of cells to the right). 2. For this excellent method of user @egreg one needs to set the linebreaks manually; for `multirow` one doesn't need to.

Comment: This wins the prize for the most incomprehensible answer.

Comment: This will not work if you want to bold the text.

Comment: @user230137 Just use `\bfseries` before `\specialcell`

Comment: Seems incomprehensible at first but easiest to execute I feel.

Comment: What are t, b and c abbreviations for? Thanks. I'm new (72 hours) to LaTeX.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen You can say `\begin{tabular}[t]{<cols>}`, `\begin{tabular}[b]{<cols>}` or `\begin{tabular}[c]{<cols>}`. The last is the same as `\begin{tabular}{<cols>}`. The optional argument specifies the vertical alignment of the tabular with respect to the context: with respect to the `t`op line, the `b`ottom line or to the table `c`enter.

Comment: Great! Thanks! And if you change {@{}c@{}} to {@{}l@{}} then the text becomes horizontally left aligned, which was an additional desire for me. Thumbs up for the original answer and your additional help. Thanks.

Comment: Egreg's solution is one of the most interesting and efficient I ever seen for line breaking at tables! Thanks. However, I made a slight change to specify the alignment directly from the command \specialcell:
\newcommand{\specialcell}[3][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#2@{}}#3\end{tabular}}%

which should be called by \specialcell{<align>}{text1\\text2}
where <align> must be replaced by the desired position: l (left), c (center), r (right). Despite this mod, all credits to @egreg.

Comment: I couldn't get the vertical alignment to work. It was always bottom aligned.

Comment: @Fractaly Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! In contrast to @RickyRobinson, I think this is probably the best answer since it doesn't require the use of an additional package!

Comment: Can someone please tell me how it can be vertically left aligned?

Comment: @AbuShoeb Change  `@{}c@{}` into `@{}l@{}` 9you may want different commands for the different alignments, though).

Comment: This is the most versatile answer!

Comment: @EthanAlvaree I suspect you’re using double spacing, is it so?

Comment: This answer seems to cope with whole table scaling (using `\tiny`, for example) in a much better way than using the `makecell` package.

Answer (score 269):

You can switch your cell layout to paragraph to use the `\newline` command.

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
Test & foo \newline bar \\
...
```

**Edit**:

Use the following commands instead of `p` if you want to specify the alignment as well:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

Comment: I did. I tried both `\newline` and `\linebreak`, but they only work in paragraph mode. http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cgi-comment/info2html?(latex)%5Cnewline

Comment: Hmm. I thought it did. I could have sworn I've done this before. The only thing I can think of right now is to put a single column tabular within the other tabular. E.g., Foo bar & \begin{tabular}{c} Foo \\ bar \end{tabular} & foo bar \\

Comment: @frabjous: Could you clarify the status of this answer? Does it work, and if so, how? (A complete MWE would be good.)

Comment: @doncherry: This answer works, _iff_ your column type is `p{width}` or `X` (in a `tabularx` environment). It _does not_ work with `c`, `l` or `r` columns, as requested by the asker, though.

Comment: +1 This solution (unlike some others I've tried) also works well with \rowcolors

Comment: @doncherry I added a work around which will allow you to specify the alignment as well.

Comment: By far the simplest solution!

Answer (score 234):

You can use this:

```
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
    \pbox{20cm}{This is the first \\ cell} & second \\ \hline
    3rd & and the last cell \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

which looks like:

[image: split cell with pbox]

Note that the width supplied to `\pbox` is a maximum width. If the content is shorter the length of the longest line is taken.

Comment: This may be an obvious question. What is the 20cm for, and is there a way to remove it? (automatically choose the correct value)

Comment: The `\pbox` solution is great. Alignment might be a bit tricky. If you run into trouble using this solution, see here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55861/13450

Comment: How to center the new line?

Comment: Well, it’s still overly complicated because it’s a fixed width, but on the other hand I don’t want to be Mr Complainy Pants.

Comment: `adjustbox` has trouble with this package. Use `makecell` as described at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176780/9075. Then, you can do a top alignment using `\adjustbox{valign=t}{...}`

Comment: I extend this solution in my code by `\newcommand{\multilinebox}[1]{\pbox{\linewidth}{\vspace{.5\baselineskip}#1\vspace{.5\baselineskip}}}` in order to have proper spacing between the previous and next rows.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work with `tabularx`. Does it?

Comment: A note that you can use `\mbox` instead of `\pbox`, it doesn't require an additional package, and doesn't require you to specify a length. Useful if you can't install packages for whatever reason.

Comment: @JamesPaterson you can't as `\mbox` doesn't allow you to use linebreaks. You'll get a `! Missing } inserted.` error.

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür thanks. Keeping the width option works better for me: `\newcommand{\multilinebox}[2]{\pbox{#1}{\vspace{.3\baselineskip}#2\vspace{.3\baselineskip}}}`

Answer (score 164):

Use the `tabularx` environment instead of `tabular`, and then use `\newline` where you want line breaks within a cell.

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    Section:   &  This is my     \newline
                  long paragraph \\
\end{tabularx}
```

The `tabularx` environment has a special column type, `X`, in addition to the usual ones, and its first argument is the desired width of the table. The `X` column will have the necessary width in order to make the whole table the desired width.

*Note*: `\newline` will not take effect in columns of standard type.

Details on `tabularx` can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabularx_package).

Comment: Nice one, I hadn't realised `tabularx` supported this, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: By far the easiest solution!

Comment: How does this work? I'm not getting the desired output.

Comment: @CroCo, add the `\usepackage...` line in your `main.tex` and the rest of the code shown works perfectly. **+1 for this answer**, which does not only work for `\newline` but also allows many other commands and even environments `\begin{...} ... \end{...}`, which was all very forbidden in the normal `tabular` environment.

Comment: the main point of using tabularx is to having those newlines added automatically, which makes this kinda pointless. tabularx can be the right answer to this, if the answer is forget about manually introducing the newline and just rely on tabularx.

Comment: @carandraug, note that the question asks specifically for a _forced_ line break, so the explicit `\newline` is not pointless.

Comment: Note: `\newline` will not take effect in columns of standard type. So how to make `\newline` to take effect on a column of a standard type?

Answer (score 86):

Here's a very simple way to do it, using Plain TeX commands within
the tabular environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
here&\vtop{\hbox{\strut top line}\hbox{\strut botline}}&more\\
\hline
x&y&z\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: table produced with code above]

By using hboxes within the vtop we've stayed in vertical mode 
and therefore the width of the text in the hboxes determines
the width of the vtop. This way we don't need to know the
width of the text in advance. `\strut` will maintain the right
space above and below the text in the hbox.

Comment: Hi Amy, and welcome to TeX.sx.  You might want to read [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and note that signing your posts is not necessary since your name appears at the bottom automatically.  See also [Rules about linking to external pages](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/908).  With respect to this particular answer, how is it different from TH's answer?

Comment: Thank you! This works when you are in a multicell but they are left aligned (even through I defined it to be in the centre). Is there a way around this?

Comment: The nice thing about this answer is that `\vtop{\hbox{\strut top line}\hbox{\strut botline}}` can be used within [Pandoc Markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) tables.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt not only that. It can be used everywhere! (because is TeX) I just needed some line break in `\text` of `\alignat` environment and worked perfectly. Thanks for this robust and simple answer!

Comment: Definitely the best answer on this page !

Answer (score 44):

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
a&\vbox{\hbox{\strut ASDF}\hbox{\strut ASDF}\hbox{\strut This is my
really long line}}&c
\end{tabular}
```

The `\strut` is essential for spacing.

Comment: This looks like good method.  Maybe too much to ask, but is there any easy way to adjust vertical justification in the cells?  E.g., so single line cells are even with top of multi-line cell?  Or so all are vertically centered?

Comment: Replace `\vbox` with `\vtop` to get alignment at the top.

Comment: Great answer.  How do you center horizontally?

Comment: @denilw: Oops. I misread and wrote a previous comment (now deleted). If you want to center the lines, the easiest way is to compute the width of the widest `\hbox` and use that as the width of the other `\hboxes`. Something like `\vbox{\setbox0\hbox{\strut This is the widest one.}\hbox to\wd0{\hss\strut ASDF\hss}\copy0\hbox to\wd0{\hss\strut asdf\hss}}`

Comment: Why is "ASDF" used for the strut?

Comment: @einpoklum, `ASDF` and `asdf` were just examples of shorter text in boxes.

Answer (score 43):

You can also just fake it:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Foo bar & Foo & Foo bar \\
~       & bar &  ~      \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 31):

Here I use stacks to accomplish it.  Several things are noteworthy:

1. I demonstrate `\Longstack` , `\Longunderstack` and `\Centerstack`, which give three different alignments.
2. In order not to squeeze against the vertical margins, a `\strutlongstacks{T}` declaration was issued.  Alternately, one might wrap a stack inside an `\addstackgap[<gap>]{content}` to add a vertical buffer above/below the stack.
3. Not shown is the ability to set the horizontal alignment of the stacked content with an optional argument, or to change the EOL character (from `\\` to another user-specified token)

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Foo bar & \Longstack{ Foo \\ bar \\ baz} & Foo bar \\
\hline
Foo bar & \Longunderstack{ Foo \\ bar \\ baz} & Foo bar \\
\hline
Foo bar & \Centerstack{ Foo \\ bar} & Foo bar \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is gorgeous! I'm wondering why it has so few votes...

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks for the kind words.  I think that I give so many answers with stacks, people are of the opinion, "you seen one, you seen 'em all."  I am a victim of my own success.

Comment: It's really a pity that people stop at the first answers! :)

Comment: This really helped me and this is so simple to use!

Comment: @ShahadMahmud I'm happy that you find the package useful.

Answer (score 18):

This is a really old question, but since this was linked from a recent question on [separating content and presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68940/323), I'll add a ConTeXt answer for comparision.

In ConTeXt, `\crlf` adds a forced line-break, so achieving a forced line-break in a table is as simple as just adding `\crlf` in the appropriate place. Here is the complete example:

```
% Setup for rules at the top and bottom
\startsetups table:rules
  \setupTABLE[frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[row][first][topframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[row][last][bottomframe=on]
\stopsetups

% Setups for middle alignment
\startsetups table:middle
  \setupTABLE[align=middle]
\stopsetups

\starttext

\startTABLE[setups={table:rules, table:middle}]
  \NC Foo bar \NC Foo \crlf Bar \NC Foo bar \NC \NR
  \NC Foo bar \NC Foo \crlf Bar \NC Foo bar \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: your source code does not match what the illustration shows.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle: It does for me! Which version of context are you using?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your question earlier. My context is v. 0.60 (2013.04.20 01:15). However, now re-testing your code, I can confirm that your code works. I have to withdraw my previous statement. Can't remember now what caused me to make it.

Comment: As usual, [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page) is easiest with its `\crlf` (carriage return linefeed) [command](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/crlf).

Answer (score 14):

How about using `\parbox` in a custom command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\mylength
\newcommand\boxup[2]{%
  \savebox\mybox{#1}%
  \setlength\mylength{\wd\mybox}%
  \parbox{\mylength}{#1 \\ #2}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
Foo bar & \boxup{Foo}{bar} & Foo bar \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This takes two arguments with the assumption that the first line is longer than the second. It would be possible to refine the code to work through an arbitrary number of lines and find the longest. If that's of interest I'll write something, probably using [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) for the looping.

Comment: Gives me issues with too little vertical spacing. \vspace only helps for the bottom margin.

Answer (score 14):

I believe I have the simplest answer here:

If you are using a paragraph column in a table, you can put text in an alignment environment and the table does not pick up the `\\` as a new table row, so you can use it normally. For example:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2in}p{2in}}
    \begin{flushleft}
        Some text over here \\ 
        newline! \\ 
        \bigskip all the way down 
    \end{flushleft} 
    & 
    \begin{flushleft}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
        adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
        magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo\\ \bigskip
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\\ 
        \bigskip \bigskip lorem ipsum\\
    \end{flushleft}\\
\end{tabular}\
```

Will give you a table with line breaks using the `\\` command.

Comment: I think the explanation is wrong - I just tried `{flushleft}` in a `l` column, and it fails; I think the reason why this example works is because it has `p{2in}` column type, which sets the width in advance..

Answer (score 13):

I think `multirow` is a simple elegant solution, at least for simple tables.

For example, I tried a few of the suggestions above but I found this worked the best:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{RESTful Resources}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l l l}
        \hline
        Resource & Methods & Description \\
        \hline 
        \multirow{2}{*}{Resource1} & \multirow{2}{*}{POST, PUT} 
            & This resource contains ...\\
          & & \emph{Media types: text/plain, application/json}\\
        \multirow{2}{*}{Resource2} & \multirow{2}{*}{POST, PUT} 
            & This resource contains ...\\
          & & \emph{Media types: text/plain, application/json} \\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:resources}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't have direct help on how to add a linebreak, but using the multirow package may provide different route to same desired end.  You can read a tutorial here:

http://andrewjpage.com/index.php?/archives/43-Multirow-and-multicolumn-spanning-with-latex-tables.html

But I have a feeling the \parbox answer in the similar question you linked is what you're looking for.  I think using a box in the cell is going to be simplest and best way, was there something about that that wasn't working for you?

If you want to use parbox without having to hardcode in a width, here's one way that works for me.  Not perfect, since it requires you to know beforehand the text of the longest line in the multi-line column, but it does work:

```
% define new length and set to length of longest line
\newlength{\longline}
\settowidth{\longline}{longest line in table}\\

\begin{tabular}{lll}

one line & \parbox[t]{\longline}{longest line in table \\ and another line} & more text \\
second line here& and what & more text 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: `\parbox` works, but it requires me to type the desired column width. Thus, I lose the auto-column-size that happens otherwise. I bet `\multirow` will work, but the source-code will be a lot messy.

Comment: Gotcha.  Added code sample to my question that uses column autosizing with parbox and is probably cleaner than using multirow package.  I think there must be a better way, but at least it works. . .

Answer (score 8):

It’s easy peasy to write multiline cells without fixing the column width with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray): just enclose the cell text with braces and use `\\` to break lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
 Left & {Center \\ Cent \\ C} & {Right \\ R} \\
\hline
 {L \\ Left} & {C \\ Cent \\ Center} & R \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It seems there is a rather simple solution. Just wrap the text into currly braces and use `\raggedright` like this:

```
{\raggedright \bfseries WS 2016 \\(average)}
```

Here is a simple example:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[ht]{|X|p{1.8cm}|}
  \hline
  Some Longer Column &
  {\raggedright \bfseries Line \\Break} \\\hline
  This is a wide line with some text & Small \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: This only works in `p` (or `X`) columns, but not in `l`, `r`, or `c` columns.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `minipage` environment:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\columnwidth}%
This is the first line
\newline
second line
\newline
...
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: You have to specify width in advance, though...

Answer (score 4):

When I was younger I was typesetting a `tabular` environment inside a `tabular` environment. Since we have Ti*k*Z I use the `tikzpicture` environment inside tabulars, or even a `tikzpicture` inside a `tikzpicture`. I prefer putting simple Ti*k*Z nodes next and below each other, but it depends on actual task. I enclose an MWE with fast text height correction.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{inner sep=0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[align=left, text height=4.5ex]{This is the\\[3pt]first cell};
\end{tikzpicture} 
    & second \\ \hline
    3rd & and the last cell \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

![MWE][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Gjo.png

Comment: ```\tikz \node[align=left, text height=4.5ex]{This is the\\[3pt]first cell};``` is a more brief variant.

Answer (score 3):

This approach isn't so different from some of the others already given, except that it "externalises" all of the design decisions from the table definition itself (that is, leaving it cleaner to write and read each table should you want to include multiple tables like this throughout your doc or docs).

Preliminaries (presumably in your preamble):

```
\usepackage{array} % needed if you're going to use \\ together with centering,
                   % raggedright, raggedleft in your column specifier (see
                   % manuals on \arraybackslash)
\newlength{\mywidestcolwidth}
\newcommand*\mycellformat{\protect\footnotesize}
\newcommand*\mytableparskip{\setlength\parskip{4pt}}
\newcommand*\setmywidestcolwidth[1]{
  \settowidth{\mywidestcolwidth}{\mycellformat #1}
}
```

Usage:

```
\setmywidestcolwidth{foo baz bar}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\mycellformat}c
                |>{\mytableparskip\mycellformat\centering\arraybackslash}p{\mywidestcolwidth}
                |>{\mycellformat}c|}
\hline
foo bar baz&
foo

foo baz bar

baz& 
foo

foo baz bar

baz\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Skip the `\mycellformat` and `\parskip` if you have no need for them (although not necessary in your case, I included `\parskip` since it's useful to visually distinguish paragraphs from one another since paragraph  indentation is automatically switched off in tables, and added `\mycellformat` to allow for uniform document-wide table design settings).

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer to use `\usepackage{multirow} \multirow{"number of rows"}{"width"}{"contents"}` for everything else except the information that should be on different rows.

For example:

```
 \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}@{\hskip 0mm}  p{5cm}@{\hskip 4mm} p{5cm} }
     Parameter & Description & Used by\\
     \hline
     \\[-0.1cm]
     \multirow{2}{*}{Accuracy}&1. The error rate or frequency of correctness of sensor readings.  & \\[0.3cm]
     & 2. The degree of correspondence of measured values to actual values.& \\[0.3cm]
      \hline
      \\[-0.1cm]
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: This works even without the multirow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`adjustbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Foo bar & \adjustbox{stack=ll}{Foo\\bar} & Foo bar \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35135/1347).

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2442/250119) suggests using `p`-type column and `\newline` command.

However, once you realize that `p`-type column is just typesetted in a `\parbox` (basically a vbox in plain TeX), a paragraph break works.

[image: unofficial documentation]

So:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
  hello
  
  world&hello

  world
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure why nobody have suggested that
given how [`⟨blank line⟩` is preferred over `\newline` or `\\` in normal text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664/250119).

Perhaps it's because of semantic meaning -- you're unlikely to include a whole paragraph in a table cell. But if you do it may make sense.

E.g. the example below includes 2 paragraphs in each table cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{7cm}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus
vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor
gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh
mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci
sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan
bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi
ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante.
Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla
ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
&
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus
vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor
gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh
mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci
sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan
bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi
ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante.
Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla
ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

By default there's no first-line-indent, so the appearance
should be identical to as if `\newline` is used.

---

Another solution: [`\shortstack`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38926/250119) (similar to the nested-tabular solution this does not require specifying explicit width)

Comment: *“I'm not sure why nobody have suggested that”* → Probably because the majority of people who use LaTeX don't fully understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time, but now you can just use Optex without any packages:

```
\thistable{\tabskipl=0pt plus1fil \tabskipr=\tabskipl} % center the able
\table{p{5cm\fC}c}{%\fC centers cell
\crll
Here\break we have a broken line & As we want\crll
}

         
\bye
```

[image: broken table line]