# IEEE Tran LaTeX Template: Affiliation Block Layout

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

I want to use the [IEEE tran LaTeX class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/) for one of my **conference** papers. Three different institutions need to be affiliated and I'm trying now to design the header in a *more attractive* and functional fashion like it is shown in figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG5IY.png). As far as I know, the only design element that is provided is the `\and` command in order to influence the layout. This does not lead to a satisfying result, though, because the affiliation blocks are not aligned properly.

At the moment all insitutions are positioned in one column one after the other which chews up a lot of space, leaving a large unused area at the right side of the header page. 
Do you have any suggestions/ experience to share?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Desired Layout]

Comment: The reason for that is `IEEEtran` is designed to use `\thanks` command for the institution of the authors. The email addresses, institution etc. goes under the left column sometimes even half a column. The header space is reserved only for author names with a lot of stars daggers on them. Search for `IEEEtran how to` for the documentation.

Comment: Actually I'm even referring to the official HOWTO, @percusse.
On page 4 the following is stated:

"2) Names in Conference Mode: The author name area
is more complex when in conference mode because it also
contains the authors’ affiliations."

An example that produces a similar (unwanted) output is stated on the following page.

Comment: I added the remark, that I want to write a conference paper, though. Thank you @percusse.

Comment: Ah that's a subtle point of IEEE. Many conferences stopped using IEEEtran in the conference mode and switched to customized `\documentclass{ieeeconf}` usage. Search for the style file as recent as you can :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I eventually did was using the IEEE tran template with the following code. Looks clean and saves space.

```
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{{\bf John Doe}\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}\\ \tt\footnotesize john@domain.com} \and
\IEEEauthorblockN{{\bf Jane Doe}\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\\ \tt\footnotesize jane@domain.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Affiliate 1, Adress ...}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Affiliate 2, Adress ...}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Affiliate 3, Adress ...}
}
```

Comment: So your solution is [something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jEihf.png)
Have you found a solution for the original question? I've tried to achieve similar results with similar success. Here's what I intend to do http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141456/general-affiliation-after-author-blocks

Comment: Eric, you can't really accept this answer because you ended up not doing what you asked to do...

Answer (score 2):

I use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678) and the end result solves the original problem, is capable of retaining original formatting and alignment, doesn't require additional packages, and does not limit the number of adjacent affiliations.

```
\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{
        Author1 Name\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, 
        Author2 Name\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, and 
        Author3 Name\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
                \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}
                    Affiliation1,\\
                    Affiliation1\\
                \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}
                    Affiliation1,\\
                    Affiliation2,\\
                    Affiliation2\\
                    \{author1, author2\}@some.domain.com
            \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
                \IEEEauthorrefmark{3}
                    Affiliation3,\\
                    Affiliation3,\\
                    Affiliation3,\\
                    author3@some.domain.com
            \end{tabular}
        \end{tabular}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did what the original question asked, but only for two affiliations. The key is to use two consecutive `\and` after the authors block. Please find below the ugly hack. Notice the `\hspace{1cm}` for the first affiliation block to center the whole block w.r.t. the page. The hspace size should change depending on the longest line in the first affiliation block.

```
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author1\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
    Author2\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
    Author3\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and
    Author4\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}}
\and\and
\IEEEauthorblockA{
    \hspace{1cm}\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Affiliation1\\
    \hspace{1cm} Affiliation1\\
    \hspace{1cm}Affiliation1\\
    \hspace{1cm}\{Author1, Author3\}@affiliation.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockA{
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Affiliation2\\
    Affiliation2\\
    Affiliation2\\
    \{Author2, Author4\}@affiliation.fr}
}
```