# General Affiliation after Author Blocks

Tags: titles, ieeetran

I want to put a general 'authorblockA' for every author like this:

> ```
>          THIS IS A TITLE
>
>  George Orwel     George Campbell
> orwel@mail.com   campbell@mail.com
>
>     General Georges Asotiation.
>  Artists and writters Asotiation.
> ```

This is what I have so far:

```
\title{THIS IS A TITLE}
\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{George Orwell}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{orwell@mail.com}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{George Campbell}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{campbell@mail.com} \\
    \IEEEauthorblockA{General Georges Asotiation.}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{Artists and writters Asotiation.}
}
```

Which produces this (with wrong indentation of the two last fields):
[image: compiled pdf]

Comment: The journal decides about the layout of their journal, they will either reject the paper or revert everything back to their standards.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: No news. This was just for an assignment no Journal provided me with any template. I was curious if it could be done.

Comment: Wait, does this help? [Formatting and alignment of authors in \maketitle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309725)

Comment: Yes! thats it! Thank you. I'll keep the snippet

Comment: But in case there's a duplicate, it'll be the one you linked. My question is two years older

Comment: Correct, but yours is a bit more specific without needing that specification. And i answered the other one today, and when coming here i thought: Wait, didn't i just do that? So i flagged this as the dupe of the other. The order doesn't really mention in the long run.