# Formatting and alignment of authors in \maketitle

Tags: titles, templates

I am in the process of creating a LaTeX template for a conference submission, and up until now I've been working only with the anonymous submissions. Now I need to create the "camera-ready" version, which means I need to add authors to the document.

The template is based on `article.cls`, with some tweaks to meet the font and formatting specifications. The following image contains the examples from the Word template for the conference:

[image: Author formatting requirements]

Basically, I need to be able to bold the author's name (which could I suppose be done manually in the document rather than in the template) and more importantly: divide the authors into two columns, with an optional centered last column with an odd number of authors. The font size of the author block corresponds to my `\LARGE` defined in the class file.

Are there any packages that facilitate this type of conditional formatting, either in a document, or in a `.cls` file? How can I use those packages to achieve the formatting I require?

Comment: [`authblk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/authblk)  [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you for the package recommendations. Any direction for how to use those to achieve what I'm looking for. I don't think `authblk` fits what I need, but `titling` might. I've looked at the documentation, but don't really understand how to bend it to my will.

Answer (score 4):

Better late than never.

Redefining a bit of stuff should get you what you want.

[image: RyanAuthorsThree]

[image: RyanAuthorsFour]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{array}
\preauthor{\begin{center}
    \large \lineskip .75em%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}}}
        \postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\and{%                  % \begin{tabular}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}}}%   % \end{tabular}
  \makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{This is a story of great friends}
\author{Wombat \\ Australia \and
    Capybara \\ Brasil \and
    Mara \\ Patagonia \and
Nasenb\"ar \\ M\"onchengladbach}
\maketitle
\blindtext
\end{document}
```