# Write column header on multiple line

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)

I would like to write the header of a column on multiple line. I tried with this commands but it doesn't work:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline \\
$\alpha$ 
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{GallusGallus \\ CC \\ t = 104}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{GallusGallus \\ MF \\ t = 124}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{GallusGallus \\ BP \\ t = 110}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{BosTaurus \\ CC \\ t = 99}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{BosTaurus \\ MF \\ t = 217}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{BosTaurus \\ BP \\ t = 205}
\end{tabular}
```

How can I fix?

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678/4427

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `P{<width>}{<contents>}` instead of using `c` column. In `p` (paragraph) column, usual `\centering` can be used to center the contents.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\hline 
$\alpha$
& \multicolumn{1}{|p{3cm}|}{\centering GallusGallus \\ CC \\ t = 104}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Your full example will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline 
$\alpha$
& \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\centering GallusGallus \\ CC \\ t = 104}
& \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\centering GallusGallus \\ MF \\ t = 124}
& \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\centering GallusGallus \\ BP \\ t = 110}
& \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\centering BosTaurus \\ CC \\ t = 99}
& \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\centering BosTaurus \\ MF \\ t = 217}
& \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\centering BosTaurus \\ BP \\ t = 205}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does removing `\centering` cause all sorts of errors?

Comment: @Cyrille What sort of error do you get?

Comment: It creates the PDF fine with the centering. I remove `\centering` and run again and get the following repeated a ~hundred times until a fatal error occurs: `Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} ...|p{2cm}|}{ GallusGallus \\ CC \\ t = 104}` and `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.<recently read> \egroup ...|p{2cm}|}{ GallusGallus \\ CC \\ t = 104}`

Comment: @Cyrille It compiles fine for me after removing `\centering`.

Comment: That's what I would have expected... Hmm oh well. A bug perhaps. Using a OS X 10.10.1 for the record. I will update Tex... Thanks!

Comment: @Cyrille I just want to confirm that I have the same issue on my mac, I can't remove the \centering.

Comment: @Cyrille, I got the same problem on Windows 7, using TexMaker.

Comment: How can you shift \alpha down to the 3rd row? \\ does not work.