# Wrapping or adding line breaks in header cell of siunitx's S-type column

Tags: tables, siunitx

When using the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, is it possible to either "wrap" or insert line breaks in the header cell of an `S`-type column (see [Section 4.6 of the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf))?

I have a relatively long table wherein I'd like to do this.

Below, I show the general usage of the `S`-type column. Then, I (kind of) mimic what what to achieve using a `p`-type column, but it would be nice to be able to wrap the header while taking advantage of `siunitx`'s `S`-type column.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx, booktabs}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\setlength\parindent{0em}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cSSS@{}}
    \toprule
      &
      {Reaction 1 (\si{\mmol\per\s})} &
      {Reaction 2 (\si{\umol\per\minute})} &
      {Reaction 3 (\si{\pmol\per\hour})} \\
    \midrule
      Item 1 & 10 & 12 & 15 \\
      Item 2 & 20 & 22 & 25 \\
      Item 3 & 30 & 32 & 35 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \par\bigskip
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cp{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}@{}}
    \toprule
      &
      {Reaction 1 (\si{\mmol\per\s})} &
      {Reaction 2 (\si{\umol\per\minute})} &
      {Reaction 3 (\si{\pmol\per\hour})} \\
    \midrule
      Item 1 & 10 & 12 & 15 \\
      Item 2 & 20 & 22 & 25 \\
      Item 3 & 30 & 32 & 35 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can nest any construct that allows linebreaking (a `tabular` or `\parbox`, or here I use `\shortstack` for a change)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx, booktabs}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\setlength\parindent{0em}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cSSS@{}}
    \toprule
      &
      {\shortstack{Reaction 1\\(\si{\mmol\per\s})}} &
      {\shortstack{Reaction 2\\(\si{\umol\per\minute})}} &
      {\shortstack{Reaction 3\\(\si{\pmol\per\hour})}} \\
    \midrule
      Item 1 & 10 & 12 & 15 \\
      Item 2 & 20 & 22 & 25 \\
      Item 3 & 30 & 32 & 35 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tabular` and `\parbox` give me error messages. `\shortstack` doesn't, but it vertically aligns the last line of the cell with the first line of the cells in the other columns, which is ugly. Frankly, I'm baffled why `siunitx` doesn't try to reproduce the functionality of `p` columns.

Answer (score 0):

`\shortstack` didn't work for me, so I used

```
\mbox{\specialcell{\textbf{24 GiB}\\\textbf{96 processors}}}
```

where `\specialcell` was defined by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) in [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678/) as

```
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
```

Example:

```latex
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|S[table-format=4.2]|S[table-format=4.2]|}
    \textbf{Mount option} & \textbf{Backend API} & \specialcell{\textbf{MPI hint}\\\textbf{configuration}} & \mbox{\specialcell{\textbf{12 GiB}\\\textbf{(48 processors)}}} & \mbox{\specialcell{\textbf{24 GiB}\\\textbf{(96 processors)}}} \\
    % ...
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which results in:
[image: 1]]