# Problem on coding table in latex

Tags: tables

I am wondering if you can help me on coding a table using LaTeX. I have
difficulty in doing it.

This is the code I have done:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.40in,right=0.40in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\author{}
\title{\fontsize{18}{28}\bf {A 0-1 Integer programming Formulation for solving the College Student-project assignment problem}}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
The assignment process for graduated students at the beginning of each semester is an 

important process for all academic programs at Benghazi University. This paper presents a model that includes a number of constraints relating to the minimum and maximum number of students in each academic program and the prerequisites and corequisites for each project in each academic program. The objective is to determine a way to assign students to projects according to their preferences. A linear grade function that represents the preferences of each student is introduced to be maximized. A 0-1 integer programming formulation is proposed that was implemented using data from the 2008 fall and 2009 spring semesters in the Industrial Engineering and Manufacturing Systems Department at the University of Benghazi in Benghazi, Libya. The assignment solutions were obtained using different preference criterions and were then compared with the solutions previously obtained using a manual system.\\
\end{abstract}
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{scriptsize}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Comparison between IMPROVE algorithm, developed IMPROVE algorithm with other earlier approaches} \label{table_example}
\centering
\scalebox{0.84}{
\begin{tabular} {|c|p{1cm}|c|c|p{1cm}|c|p{1cm}|c|p{1cm}|c|p{1cm}|c|p{1cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
%{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccccccccccccccc}
     \hline

  \begin{sideways}Case\end{sideways}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Solution \linebreak source} & Approach &Cell &  exceptional elements&  void element & Grouping index &  Cell &  exceptional elements &  void element & Grouping index &  Cell &  exceptional elements &  void element & Grouping index \\

    \hline
1   &   Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & $0.65^b$ & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1   &   Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & $0.65^b$ & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1   &   Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & $0.65^b$ & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1   &   Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & $0.65^b$ & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1   &   Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & $0.65^b$ & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1   &   Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & $0.65^b$ & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1   &   Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & $0.65^b$ & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1   &   Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & $0.65^b$ & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need code that can generate the same table as in the figure.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, you can use the image button to upload the image but remove the `!` from the generated markup. That will make a link, then someone with edit rights will add the `!` back later. Thanks for the example code but in future please always post complete documents from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` which shows the packages loaded and (important here) the page and font sizes being used.

Comment: There is no one know how to code like this table !!! Or it is impossible to do exactly like this table in latex.

Answer (score 2):

To create the table you provided with your picture I used the following code (some highlights about it at the end):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.40in,right=0.40in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} 
\author{} 
\title{\fontsize{18}{28}\bf {A 0-1 Integer programming Formulation for solving the College Student-project assignment problem}} \date{\today}     \begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\begin{abstract} The assignment process for graduated students at the beginning of each semester is an important process for all academic programs at Benghazi University. This paper presents a model that includes a number of constraints relating to the minimum and maximum number of students in each academic program and the prerequisites and corequisites for each project in each academic program. The objective is to determine a way to assign students to projects according to their preferences. A linear grade function that represents the preferences of each student is introduced to be maximized. A 0-1 integer programming formulation is proposed that was implemented using data from the 2008 fall and 2009 spring semesters in the Industrial Engineering and Manufacturing Systems Department at the University of Benghazi in Benghazi, Libya. The assignment solutions were obtained using different preference criterions and were then compared with the solutions previously obtained using a manual system. 
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} 

\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth} 
\captionof{table}{Comparison between IMPROVE algorithm, developed IMPROVE algorithm with other earlier approaches} \label{table_example} 
\centering 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ 
\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline 
\multirow{5}{*}{\begin{sideways}Case\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{5}{*}{Solution source} & 
\multirow{5}{*}{Approach} & 
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Performance measures of} & 
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Performance measures of} & 
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Performance measures of} \\
 & & & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Methods} &
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{IMPROVE algorithm} &
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{developed IMPROVE algorithm} \\ \cline{4-15}
 & & & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\#\\Cell\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\#\\exceptionnal\\element\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\# void\\element\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Grouping\\index\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\#\\Cell\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\#\\exceptionnal\\element \end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\# void\\element\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Grouping\\index\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\#\\Cell\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\#\\exceptionnal\\element\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\# void\\element\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Grouping\\index\end{tabular}} \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline 
1 & Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19\footnotemark[2] & 246 & 0.65 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1 & Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246\footnotemark[2] & 0.65 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1 & Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & 0.65 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1 & Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & 0.65 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1 & Kusiak & With p=2\footnotemark[1] & 2& 19 & 246 & 0.65 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1 & Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & 0.65 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1 & Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & 0.65 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
1 & Kusiak & With p=2 & 2& 19 & 246 & 0.65 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 & 2 & 13 & 232 & 0.67 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}} 
\footnotetext[1]{$\,$ First footnote} 
\footnotetext[2]{$\,$ Second footnote} 
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

First of all I've added the `caption` package for two things: to add the option to center the caption and to use the `\captionof` command which allows to create a caption outside a float.

I then renamed the footnote from number to small letters as it is on your picture.

In order to have the footnotes just after the table and note at the end of the page, a trick is to use a minipage environment to surround the table. The footnotes will be displayed at the end of the minipage environment.

I played around with the `multirow` and `multicolumn` functions to get an aspect as close as possible to your picture. The hardest was to fit 2 lines in 3. The trick here is to use the solution mentionned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678/31058).

There is still some work to fill the table but the mostly the layout part is done.

Here is the table I got with my code:[image: The table obtained]