# How to add two force line breaks in cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I would like to add two force line breaks in a cell. Using an answer from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2441/8380) I can add one force line break. Can you help to add two line breaks using similar function like

```
   \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
   \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
```

Comment: that makes an inner tabular so you can have as many `\\ ` as you want forcing a new line

Comment: I understand now, it works. Can you post your answer, so that I can mark it answered? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That makes an inner tabular so you can have as many `\\` as you want forcing a new line

```
\specialcell{aa\\bb\\cc}
```