# how to break lines in a table?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

my code is here

```
\begin{table}[t]
 \centering
 \bgroup
 \def\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
Frucht graph & Graph $K_3$ & An homomorphism from Frucht graph to $K_3$\\       \hline
\multirow{12}{*}{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{Frucht.eps}} & \multirow{12}{*}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{K_3.eps}} &  $f(1)$ = Red\\&&$f(2)$ = Blue\\ &&$f(3)$ = Red\\ &&$f(4)$ = Green\\ &&$f(5)$ = Blue\\ &&$f(6)$ = Green\\ &&$f(7)$ = Blue\\ &&$f(8)$ = Red\\ &&$f(9)$=Blue\\&&$f(10)$=Blue\\&&$f(11)$=Red \\&&$f(12)$=Green\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\caption{Graph isomorphism.}
\end{table}
```

it appears alike this:
[image]

However, because the line 'An homomorphism from Frucht graph to $K_3$' is too line, it exceed the width of the document. I prefer to break it into two lines, and let 'Frucht graph' and 'Graph K_3' in the center. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: This is basically the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest `\tabular` environments, and you can use this idea to improve your table in two ways.

To get the line break in the heading just change the head line to this:

```
Frucht graph & Graph $K_3$ 
& \begin{tabular}{c}An homomorphism from\\Frucht graph to $K_3$\end{tabular}\\
```

Secondly you can use a nested tabular to make the third data cell and therefore avoid the need for the complicated `\multirow` set up.

You might also like to use some colour in the text with the `xcolor` package and to make the equations look a bit better by putting the text inside the maths.

Here is a complete example (albeit with my versions of your graphics clipped from your example).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Frucht graph & Graph $K_3$ & \begin{tabular}{c}An homomorphism from\\Frucht graph to $K_3$\end{tabular}
    \\[8pt]
    \hline
    \lower1.6cm\hbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Frucht.png}}
    &
    \lower1.4cm\hbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{K3-graph.png}}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{l}
     \\[-6pt]
     $  f(1) = \color{Red}  \text{Red}  $\\
     $  f(2) = \color{Blue} \text{Blue} $\\ 
     $  f(3) = \color{Red}  \text{Red}  $\\ 
     $  f(4) = \color{Green}\text{Green}$\\ 
     $  f(5) = \color{Blue} \text{Blue} $\\ 
     $  f(6) = \color{Green}\text{Green}$\\ 
     $  f(7) = \color{Blue} \text{Blue} $\\ 
     $  f(8) = \color{Red}  \text{Red}  $\\ 
     $  f(9) = \color{Blue} \text{Blue} $\\
     $ f(10) = \color{Blue} \text{Blue} $\\
     $ f(11) = \color{Red}  \text{Red}  $\\
     $ f(12) = \color{Green}\text{Green}$\\[6pt]  
     \end{tabular}
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note the adjustments to the line spacing.  And the need to put the graphics into boxes and artificially lower the baselines, so that they line up nicely with the nested `tabular`.  You may need to alter the amount that the boxes are lowered by when you use your own graphics.

The output with my versions of your pictures looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @Thurston Wow, it looks so gut! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Thurson, I tried, this will cause a new problem that the two figures are not vertical center but on the top, how can I solve it?

Comment: I'll update the answer to show you.  But you should read the wikibooks entry on tables for more information.

Comment: @Ginger you might like to read more [here on wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).