# Centering text in a table cell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I know the question has been asked before, but the answers don't seem to apply. I have a table defined below:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\caption[Micromagnetic simulators]{Micromagnetic simulators. \citesource{Kim2010}.\label{tab:sims}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Developers} & \textbf{Open Source} & \textbf{Method} \\
\hline LLG Simulator & M. R. Scheinfein & Paid & FDM \\
\hline MAGPAR & W. Scholtz & Free & FEM \\ 
\hline {\centering MicroMagus} & D. V. Berkov & Paid & FDM \\ & and N. L. Gorn & & \\ 
\hline Nmag & H. Fangohr & Free & FEM \\ & and T. Fischbacher & & \\ 
\hline OOMMF & M. Donahue & Free & FDM \\ & and D. Porter & & \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

This gives a table as below:

[image]

As you may notice `{\centering MicroMagus}` did not succeed in centring the entry. Also, how would  you rate my table in terms of good practices etc?

Comment: `\centering` is for horizontal centering, do you want vertical centering?

Comment: The entry is centred (due to the c column) `\centering` does nothing in gorizontal mode. If it were a `p` column (a `\parbox` then `\centering MicroMagus` would (horizontally) center buy `{\centering MicroMagus}` will never center anything as centering and similar commands always require the end of paragraph to be in scope, and the `{}` means that centering is turned off before the end of paragraph.  If you want vertical centering try `\raisebox{-7pt}{MicroMagus}`

Comment: Regarding good practices; I would suggest to loose all the rules and left-align everything (i.e., `\begin{tabular}{llll}`).

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `multirow` package for that. Here is a code that works:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption[Micromagnetic simulators]{Micromagnetic simulators.\citesource{Kim2010}.\label{tab:sims}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Developers} & \textbf{Open Source} & \textbf{Method} \\
\hline
LLG Simulator & M. R. Scheinfein & Paid & FDM \\
\hline
MAGPAR & W. Scholtz & Free & FEM \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{MicroMagus} & D. V. Berkov & Paid & FDM \\
& and N. L. Gorn & & \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Nmag} & H. Fangohr & Free & FEM \\
& and T. Fischbacher & & \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{OOMMF} & M. Donahue & Free & FDM \\
& and D. Porter & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Note that I replaced the `center` environment, that gives a spurious vertical space, with the `\centering` command.
[image]

Comment: Bernard, remember that you can upvote questions and answers you like!

Comment: @karlkoeller How do I upvote?

Comment: Bernard, next to each answer or question, you can see two arrows with a number in the middle. The one above is to upvote, the one below is to downvote. For example, you can click on the arrow above the "1" on the above question and you'll give reputation to the OP. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour for more info.