# Breakline inside tabular whilst keeping the automatic line wrapping

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I declared a macro like this:

```
\newcommand{\itemcell}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}
}
```

Yet, I am now struggling with this, because it does not allow an automatic line wrapping anymore. See the example below :

```
\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{\dimexpr\columnwidth-9.1cm-12\tabcolsep\relax}}
\toprule
Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4 & Title 5 & Title 6 \\
\midrule
a       & b       & c       & d       & e       & \itemcell{This is a very long description which won't fit in 1 line, it should break, but it won't\\And this is a second line} \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

The content of the `\itemcell{}` won't be wrapped at the end of the column, overfull `hbox` incoming.

How can I arrange this macro to get that default behaviour back ?

Comment: your columns are `p` columns so just remove `\itemcell` it does nothing other than prevent line breaking.

Comment: to force a newline in a `p` column use a paragraph break (if it is a new paragraph) or `\linebreak` or `\newline` if you just want to manually break a line.

Comment: And I would really like to know *where* on this website `\itemcell` is recommended. A search return nothing.

Comment: You could use `\itencell` in a `l` column to allow line breaking, but it is missing a `%` at the end of the line in its definition.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : I renamed it, but here, among others : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell

Comment: As I say above, use `\newline` or `\linebreak` (depending on whether you want the line to be cut short or be justified) just as in normal text outside of a table.

Comment: The example you refer to is in a `c` column which does not allow multiple lines, so it is designed to locally over-ride that.

Comment: Well you misunderstood the context, the purpose and the use of the command. In p-columns you don't need it, simply use `\newline` or `\par`(or an empty line) to get a paragraph break. And in other column types it can only be used for *short* bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` columns allow line breaking so the macro is not needed at all, just use

```
\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{\dimexpr\columnwidth-9.1cm-12\tabcolsep\relax}}
\toprule
Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4 & Title 5 & Title 6 \\
\midrule
a       & b       & c       & d       & e       &
This is a very long description which won't fit in 1 line, it should break, but it won't

And this is a second line\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

in a `c` column you can locally use the nested tabular to allow multiple lines with manual line breaking, but your definition adds spurious white space as it is missing a `%`

```
\newcommand{\itemcell}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%%%%
}
```