# Extra spacing in cell using \pbox in \pgfplotstabletypeset

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I am using a straight-forward `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

Because I wanted to insert a manual break in one of the cells to decrease the width of that cell, I added a `\pbox` as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11555

The problem is that the resulting height is a little bit too small for my taste:
[image: table]

As you can see, "some" is at the very top of the cell and "text" at the very bottom. I'd like to have a small extra space at the top and at the bottom.

I was not able to achieve this with the stuff I tried.

Any ideas?

Here is the minimal working example that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
    column type=l,
    every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,
    after row=\midrule},
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}}},
    every odd row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}}},
    every last row/.style={
    after row=\bottomrule},
    col sep = &,
    row sep=\\,
    string type,
}

\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\pgfplotstabletypeset{
a & b \\
1 & 2 \\
\pbox[c]{20cm}{some \\ long \\ text} & foo \\
3 & 4 \\
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Bernard, thank you for your suggestion that you posted below.

There is a problem, however, when longer lines are present in the table.

Please add the following row to the minimal working example that you posted:

```
\makecell{some even longer \\ text that spans \\ three lines}  & foo \\
```

This will result in the following table:

[image]

You said that the same resulting table can be obtained without pgfplotstable. That's fine with me - If you have a suggestion how to do it differently, I'm open to use that as well.

Note to Paul Gaborit: I posted my original question as an anonymous user, so I cannot comment on my own or any other comment when I come back to this page, or?

Comment: Trouble accessing your account?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `makecell` package, instead of `\pbox`: this package allows for linebreaks in table cells with its `\makecell`, `\thead`, `\rotcell` and `\rothead` commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
    column type=l,
    every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,
    after row=\midrule},
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}}},
    every odd row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}}},
    every last row/.style={
    after row=\bottomrule},
    col sep = &,
    row sep=\\,
    string type,
}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\pgfplotstabletypeset{
a & b \\
1 & 2 \\
\makecell{some \\ long \\ text} & foo \\
3 & 4 \\
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment aside: you can obtain the same resulting table without using `pgfplotstable`.