# Width of the table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

i have a problem with the the width of a table,this is the code:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|cl|c|c|}
        \hline
        & \emph{\textbf{OWL Syntaxaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}  
        & \emph{\textbf{DL syntax}} 
        & \emph{\textbf{Example}}\\ 
        \hline
        & Thing
        & $\top$  
        & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Exemplary table}
    \label{ft_tab_ex}
\end{table}
```

This is the result:
[image]

How can i do to split the word and start a new line??

Comment: Use `\tabularx` and a `X` column for the first one

Comment: @Herbert could you be more specific? i have to substitute tabular with tabularx and?

Comment: search here for `tabularx` and you'll find a lot of examples

Comment: tabularx chooses the widths automatically but you can also just do it by change change the first `c` to  `p{3cm}`  (or whatever width you need) then that may be enough or you might need explicit `\newline` commands to force line breaking if it is really a non-word like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` that tex can not break over a line

Comment: suppose "i want to break the line" instead of  aaaaa. I want that latex splits the sentence in two rows in a way that allow the table to stay in tha page

Comment: @MarcelloChiurazzi You may be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell

Comment: If TeX can break the line, it will if you just say `p{30mm}` or whatever you prefer.