# Centering vertical lines in a table

Tags: tables

I have a table that I want to span the page (to be consistent with the other tables I have) but this table has vertical lines in it and making the table span the page gives vertical lines that aren't centered:

[image: uncentered]

How can I make it so the vertical lines are horizontally centered between the columns that they separate? Removing the lines isn't an option, and I'd prefer to not use a different package (if possible).

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=3.05cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mlc}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{a table with uncentered vertical lines }
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc|ccc||c} % 
\toprule 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{cut-off} \\ \cline{3-6} \\
\mlc{Various stuff\\(MeV)} & \# of data & A & B & C & \mlc{Ref. [bleh] \\ at B } \\ 
\midrule
$np$ &&&&&\\
0 - 100 & number & value & value & value & value \\
0 - 190 & number & value & value & value & value \\
\midrule
$pp$ &&&&&\\
0 - 100 & number & value & value & value & value \\
0 - 190 & number & value & value & value & value \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Vertical lines in with `booktabs`? ;-)

Comment: Package `booktabs` assume, that table hasn't vertical lines. For table design is worth to watch http://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/ ....

Comment: @Zarko You're welcome to argue with the professor who insisted the vertical lines be there (hint: it won't work).

Comment: :-), with pleasure ... :-), but be serious, if you forced to stick with vertical lines, then don't use `booktabs`. Result i, as you can see yourself, is really terrible. And vertical lines are on the border of columns, so they per se can not be centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this code, using `tabularx` and `makecell`. Makecell allows for line breaks in tabular cells, vertical padding of cell with the `\setcellgapes` and `\makegapedcells` command, and lines with variable thickness. I was not sure whether you want vertical lines in the second row. They're easy to add if you need them. Also, I loaded `caption`for a correct vertical spacing between caption and table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[vmargin=2.54cm, left=3.05cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setcellgapes{3pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
  \makegapedcells
  \caption{a table with centred vertical lines }
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX|XXX||X} %
    \Xhline{0.08em}\noalign{\vskip1ex}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{cut-off} \\[1ex]
    \Xcline{3-6}{0.05em}
    \makecell{Various stuff \\(MeV)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\# of data} & A & B & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & \makecell{Ref. [bleh] \\ at B } \\
    \Xhline{0.05em}
    $np$ & & & & & \\
    0 - 100 & number & value & value & value & value \\
    0 - 190 & number & value & value & value & value \\
    \Xhline{0.05em}
    $pp$ & & & & & \\
    0 - 100 & number & value & value & value & value \\
    0 - 190 & number & value & value & value & value \\
    \Xhline{0.08em}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best (to my knowledge) can be done is:

[image]

Do this design your professor liked? For above table I use packages `makecell`, `multirow` and `tabu`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=3.05cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabu}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mrc[2]{\multirowcell{#1}[0pt][c]{#2\strut}}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{table}
    \abovetabulinesep=2mm
    \belowtabulinesep=2mm
\begin{tabu}to \linewidth   {*2{X[1,c]}|*3{X[1,c]}||X[1,c]}
    \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
        & \mc{}  &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{cut-off}                    \\
    \tabucline {3-6}
\mrc{1}{Various stuff\\(MeV)}       
        & \# of data          
                 & \mc{A} & B & C & \mrc{1}{Ref. [bleh] \\ at B }   \\
    \tabucline[1pt] {-}
$np$    &&&&&                                                       \\
0 - 100 & number & value & value  & value & value \\
0 - 190 & number & value & value  & value & value \\
    \tabucline {-}
$pp$    &&&&&                                   \\
0 - 100 & number & value & value  & value & value \\
0 - 190 & number & value & value  & value & value \\
    \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```