# Multi-line Multi-row cells

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to create a 4x2 table with two multi-row cells,  which join cells `(1,2)` and `(2,2)` and `(1,3)` and `(2,3)` respectively.

The 1st multi-row cell should contain 2 lines and the second 3 lines:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | D | G |
+---+   | E +---+
| H | C | F | I |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Here is my first attempt:

```
\begin{tabular}{||c|c|c|c||}\hline\hline
A & \multirow{2}{*}{B \\ C} & \multirow{2}{*}{D \\ E \\ F} & G \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{4-4}
H &   &    & I \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
```

The error (on the `multirow` line) I get is

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

and the newlines (`\\`) inside multirows are ignored.

I also tried putting `tabular` inside `multirow` (as per [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2441/46529)):

```
\begin{tabular}{||c|c|c|c||}\hline\hline
A & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{c} B \\ C \end{tabular}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{c} D \\ E \\ F \end{tabular}} & G 
   \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{4-4}
H &   &    & I \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
```

and there were no errors, but `F` was placed *below* the last two horizontal lines (i.e., the two rows in the table cannot accommodate the 3 rows in the 2nd `multirow` cell):

```
+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | D | G |
+---+   |   +---+
| H | C | E | I |
+---+---+---+---+
          F
```

The 3rd attempt was to pass an actual width in `cm` instead of `{*}` to `multirow`. This works in my case (because the chunks into which I break the multi-row cells have the same width), but the 3rd line (`F`) is still below the table - i.e., the table height is not increased to accommodate the multi-row cells.

So, my questions are:

- how can I tell multirow where to break lines?
- **how do I tell `tabular` to make space for the multi-row cells?**

Comment: Your initial sentence, regarding how the table shoul be formated is awfully hard to read/understand. Maybe it would be good to either provide a real image or at least some kind of ascii sketch.

Comment: But as far as I understand you want to have two separate rows ind the first and last column, and one row (spanning two lines), another one (spanning three lines) in the second and third coulmn?

Comment: @inVader: yes, and I added the ascii art; it is better now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose this solution. I loaded `hhline` for better intersecting double lines, and `stackengine`. The spacing required by multirow cells can be obtained with the `cellspace` package, which defines a *minimal* vertical padding for cells of columns with a qualifier prefixed by the letter `S`.

In case you really need line breaks in a `\multirow` the `makecell` package defines a`\multirowcell` command that allows for line breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{||Sc|c|c|c||}
  \hhline{|t:====:t|}
  A &
  B & \multirow{2}{*} {\setstackgap{L}{2.05ex}\Centerstack{D\\E\\F}}
  & G \\ %
  \hhline{||-|~|~|-||}
  H & C & & I \\
  \hhline{|b:====:b|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To get baselines to align better, you might try `\setstackgap{S}{3pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.6}`

Comment: Yes, but I don't like to use `\arraystretch`: as a result, the contents of a cell is no more vertically centred.I think it's better to play with `\cellspacetop/bottomlimit`.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: by the way, I first tried `\Centerstack`, instead of these nested `\stackunder`,  but all $3$ letters were superimposed. Did I miss something?

Comment: The default longstack gap is `\baselineskip`, which `tabular` sets to zero .  The fix, which I will implement if/when the package is revised, is to `\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}` instead of `\setstackgap{L}{\baselineskip}`.  Of course, the fix can be manually performed by the user, as well.

Comment: Fine! Is the default row spacing in array or matrix the same as`\normalbaselineskip`?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: I simplified the code with `\Centerstack`. Thanks for the information about longstack gap!

Comment: To answer the question of default `tabular` spacing, you can see from `\begin{tabular}{c}A\\B\end{tabular} \Centerstack{A\\B}` that they are the same spacing.  However, the introduction of `\hline`s and such will alter the spacing of `tabular`.