# newline in multirow environment

Tags: tables, line-breaking, multirow

I have a table with many multirow environment that are each compouned with many lines. 
I have seen that it is possible to break lines in multirows by fixing a particular width (with minipage for example) but I would like to decide where to break a line precisely (with a \newline for instance).

Example of current latex document :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Numbers from 1 to 5}&1 \\ 
&2 \\
&3 \\
&4 \\
&5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

What i would like to get is something like that  :

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There is several ways to do it. A very simple way is using `\shortstack`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Numbers from\\ 1 to 5}}&1 \\ 
                                                          &2 \\
                                                          &3 \\
                                                          &4 \\
                                                          &5 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{\shortstack{Numbers from\\ 1 to 5}}&1 \\ 
                                                       &2 \\
                                                       &3 \\
                                                       &4 \\
                                                       &5 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{Numbers from\\ 1 to 5}}&1 \\ 
                                                        &2 \\
                                                        &3 \\
                                                        &4 \\
                                                        &5 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I 'll go with the shortstack, thank you sir !

Comment: Why not nesting a tabular? It would be more flexible.

Comment: For some reason shortstack produces inconsistent spacing when used in multiple cells next to each other, the makecell solution by Bernard handles this much better.

Comment: Parbox works best for me, especially you can also center the text using \centering. Thank you!

Answer (score 34):

Simple with `makecell`, which is done for this sort of things: use the `\multirowcell` command (syntax even simpler than \multirow):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\multirowcell{5}{Numbers\\from\\ 1 to 5}&1 \\
&2 \\
&3 \\
&4 \\
&5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A simple option is to use the option to put a size to the column. Replace the c by `p{5cm}` with the size between the brackets.

Comment: It could work but I don't want to split my lines at different width in the same column.  In reality I am displaying mathematical formulas and for the global understanding , it is better to choose where to cut the formula.