# Containing a table within page

Tags: tables

Because the table is wider than the page, a black stripe appears at the far right. I've tried to put `\\` between words on the first line, but that doesn't appear to be the right answer since it breaks everything.

My question is what can I do for the first line (between `\toprule` and `\midrule`) to become narrower without changing the font size?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Synthesizable circuits summary.}
    \label{tab:summary}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{lccccc}
            \toprule
            $\;$ & TDC~[4] & LDO~[8] & VCO~[10] & Flash~ADC~[9] & VCO-based~ADC~[18] \\
            \midrule
            \textbf{Technology~(nm)} & 65 & 130 & 65 & 90 & 65 \\
            \textbf{Synthesizable} & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
            \textbf{Supply Voltage~(V)} & 1.2* & 0.6 & 1.2 & 1.2\textsuperscript{$\blacklozenge$} & 1.2* \\
            \textbf{Power~(mW)} & 0.010-0.150\textsuperscript{\textbullet} & --- & --- & 34.8\textsuperscript{$\blacklozenge$} & 1.4 \\
            \textbf{Dye Area~(mm\textsuperscript{2})} & 0.001 & --- & --- & 0.18 & --- \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \small
            \item * Assumed
            \item \textbullet~Normalized to 1MS/s
            \item $\blacklozenge$~One of the tested modes
            \item \textdaggerdbl~Needs 2 exterior passive components
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The resulting table:

[image: Obtained table]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Please post compilable code, if necessary removing macros not relevant to the problem (such as `\gls`).  By default latex will not print such a black bar.  Have turned on the `draft` option somewhere?

Comment: One solution would be to split some of the heading elements over two rows.

Comment: How or where is the `\gls` macro defined? Please make your code compilable without forcing your readers to guess which packages may have to be loaded.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes, `draft` option is turned ON.
I tried to split some of the heading elements with `\\` but didn't work as expected. Is there an elegant way to split the heading elements?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2441/15925 help?

Comment: I took liberty and to your MWE add missing packages and `$`, so the code now can be compiled without of error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Introducing line breaks in the header cells, not bold-facing the units, and eliminating unneeded whitespace at the left- and right-hand edges of the table makes the tabular material fit inside the text block.

Since you're using the `threeparttable` package, do make a habit of using its machinery -- `\tnote` in particular -- correctly.

(The question marks in the following question arise because the `\cite` instructions couldn't be resolved.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,amssymb,siunitx} % these three packages are also needed...
\newcommand\gls[1]{#1} % ?? % please provide the correct definition...    
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Synthesizable circuits summary.}
    \label{tab:summary}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{@{} lccccc@{}}
            \toprule
             & \gls{TDC} & \gls{B} & \gls{VCO} & Flash & \gls{VCO}-based  \\
             & \cite{A} & \cite{C} & \cite{D} & \gls{ADC}~\cite{E} & \gls{ADC}~\cite{F} \\
            \midrule
            \textbf{Technology} (\si{\nano\meter}) & 65 & 130 & 65 & 90 & 65 \\
            \textbf{Synthesizable} & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes\tnote{\textdaggerdbl} \\
            \textbf{Supply Voltage} (\si{\volt}) & 1.2\tnote{*} & 0.6 & 1.2 & 1.2\tnote{$\blacklozenge$} & 1.2\tnote{*} \\
            \textbf{Power}~(\si{\milli\watt}) & 0.010--0.150\tnote{\textbullet} & -- & -- & 34.8\tnote{$\blacklozenge$} & 1.4 \\
            \textbf{Dye Area}~(\si{\milli\meter\squared}) & 0.001 & -- & -- & 0.18 & -- \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \small
            \item[*] Assumed
            \item[\textbullet] Normalized to 1MS/s % huh?!
            \item[$\blacklozenge$] One of the tested modes
            \item[\textdaggerdbl] Needs 2 exterior passive components
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Mico answer, but for column header I suggest to use `thead` from `makecell` package, and for the first column use option `>{\bfseries}`:

**Edit:**
In the first attempt table still spill out on the right side. Table width equal to text width can be obtained with `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{...}` and than set column separation by `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{showframe}% for shoe page layout, in real application had to be deleted
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Synthesizable circuits summary.}
    \label{tab:summary}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{\bfseries}lccccc}
        \toprule
    & \thead{TDC\\ \cite{4}} & \thead{LDO\\ \cite{8}} & \thead{VCO\\ \cite{10}} 
            & \thead{Flash ADC\\ \cite{9}} & \thead{VCO-based\\ ADC \cite{18}} \\
        \midrule
Technology (nm)     & 65  & 130    & 65  & 90  & 65 \\
Synthesizable       & Yes & Yes    & Yes & Yes & Yes\tnote{\textdaggerdbl} \\
Supply Voltage (V)  & 1.2\tnote{*} & 0.6 & 1.2 & 1.2\tnote{$\blacklozenge$} & 1.2* \\
Power~(mW)          & 0.010-0.150\tnote{$\bullet$} 
                                   & --- & --- & 34.8\tnote{$\blacklozenge$}& 1.4 \\
Dye Area (mm\textsuperscript{2})
                    & 0.001        & --- & --- & 0.18 & --- \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \small
        \item[*]                Assumed
        \item[$\bullet$]        Normalized to 1MS/s
        \item[$\blacklozenge$]  One of the tested modes
        \item[\textdaggerdbl]   Needs 2 exterior passive components
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I didn't. Now I see, that last column can be narrower ... I will change this and show page layout.