# Table not fitting onto page

Tags: tables

I am having a problem with fitting a table on the page - the obvious problems are the long(ish) column titles, as well as the "Confidence Prediction" column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\caption{Confusion Matrix - Logistic Regression.} 
\label{tab1} 
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lSSlSSl} 
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1 (No Regularisation)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2 (With Regularisation)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} 
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
& 0 & 1 & Correct Predictions (\%) & 0 & 1 & Correct Predictions (\%) \\
\midrule \\
0 & 414  & 70 & 85.5 & 419 & 65 & 86.4\\ 
\addlinespace
1 & 67 & 420 & 86.2 & 58 & 429 & 88.1 \\
\midrule
\textbf{Average} &  &  & \textbf{85.9} &  & & \textbf{87.3} \\
\bottomrule \\
\end{tabular*} 
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my suggestion that is based on splitting too  long column titles into two lines and using the `table-format` option to the `S` columns.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\caption{Confusion Matrix - Logistic Regression.} 
\label{tab1} 
\begin{tabular}{l
                S[table-format=3]
                S[table-format=3]
                S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]
                S[table-format=3]
                S[table-format=3]
                S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]} 
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{Model 1 \\(No Regularisation)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{Model 2 \\ (With Regularisation)}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} 
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
& 0 & 1 & {\makecell{Correct\\ Predictions (\%)}} & 0 & 1 & {\makecell{Correct\\ Predictions (\%)}} \\
\midrule 
0 & 414  & 70 & 85.5 & 419 & 65 & 86.4\\ 
\addlinespace
1 & 67 & 420 & 86.2 & 58 & 429 & 88.1 \\
\midrule
\bfseries Average &  &  & \bfseries 85.9 &  & & \bfseries 87.3 \\
\bottomrule \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

- In order to split the column headings into two lines, I used `makecell` from the eponymous package.
- For a better formatting of the `S` colunns, I used the appropriate values for the `table-format` option. Additionally, I used `S` columns for the 4th and 7th column as well.
- In order to correct the alignment of the bold numbers in the last row, I used `etoolbox`'s `\robustify` command in combination with `\bfseries` and the `detect-weight` option of the `S` columns.

Comment: What's the advantage to using the `S` column type instead of the `r` column type for columns 2, 3, 5, and 6?

Comment: @Mico, it is just a MWE... Could be needed like this and thus OP gave this MWE

Comment: @Mico: Considering the case that the table in the MWE is already complete, there is indeed no disadvantage in using an `r` column instead of the `S` columns. Since the OP already used `S` columns in their example, I wanted to point out the usage of `table-format` that can help to get rid of unnecessary horizontal space.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that employs a `tabularx` environment, to allow automatic line-wrapping in the headers of columns 4 and 7. A centered version of the `X` column type is used for these two columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X' col.
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\caption{Confusion Matrix -- Logistic Regression.}  \label{tab1} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{2}{rrC} @{}} 
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2} \\
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{(No Regularisation)}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{(With Regularisation)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& 0 & 1 & \% Correct Predictions
& 0 & 1 & \% Correct Predictions \\
\midrule 
0 & 414  & 70 & 85.5 & 419 & 65 & 86.4\\ 
\addlinespace
1 & 67 & 420 & 86.2 & 58 & 429 & 88.1 \\
\midrule
\textbf{Average} &&& \textbf{85.9} &&& \textbf{87.3} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you don't need the table to span the full width of the textblock, a much more compact (and, in my opinion, better-looking) solution, which uses just the "standard" column types `l`, `c`, and `r`, is available:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\caption{Confusion Matrix -- Logistic Regression.} 
\label{tab1} 
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{rrc} @{}} 
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2} \\
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{(No Regularisation)}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{(With Regularisation)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& 0 & 1 & \% Correct & 0 & 1 & \% Correct \\
&&& Predictions &&& Predictions \\
\midrule 
0 & 414 &  70 & 85.5 & 419 &  65 & 86.4\\ 
\addlinespace
1 &  67 & 420 & 86.2 &  58 & 429 & 88.1 \\
\midrule
\textbf{Average} &&& \textbf{85.9} &&& \textbf{87.3} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't `siunitx` on my system and used other columntypes... Feel free to use whatever you want (for example yours).

The idea is to break some cells every where needed.

(I used this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678/120578)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\caption{Confusion Matrix - Logistic Regression.} 
\label{tab1} 
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrrrrrr} 
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\specialcell{Model 1\\ (No Regularisation)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\specialcell{Model 2 \\(With Regularisation)}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} 
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
& 0 & 1 & \specialcell{Correct\\ Predictions (\%)} & 0 & 1 & \specialcell{Correct\\ Predictions (\%)} \\
\midrule \\
0 & 414  & 70 & 85.5 & 419 & 65 & 86.4\\ 
\addlinespace
1 & 67 & 420 & 86.2 & 58 & 429 & 88.1 \\
\midrule
\textbf{Average} &  &  & \textbf{85.9} &  & & \textbf{87.3} \\
\bottomrule \\
\end{tabular*} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If this answers your question, then this is possibly a dupplicate of the linked... Also wait for other answers (if not closed)... because I have seen many times improvements and advises of any kind in table questions...

Comment: The 4th and 7th columns look a bit out of whack. Since the header cells ("Correct" and "Predictions (%)") are centered, you may want to use `c` rather than `r` as the column type for these two columns.

Comment: @Mico. I just gave the way... and asked to keep or change his own colimntypes... I didnt select better than his (OPs) but rather random...