# Problems with makecell when using tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, makecell

I'm having trouble building a document using `tex4ht` with `makecell`.

Consider the following M(n)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
 & {\thead{production \\ (kt)}}
 & {\thead{imports \\ (kt)}}
 & {\thead{import. coef. \\ (\%)}} \\
\midrule
1924 & 55138 & 2100 & 3,7 \\
1925 & 62901 & 2200 & 3,4 \\
1926 & 68708 & 2600 & 3,6 \\
1927 & 62732 & 2600 & 4,0 \\
1928 & 63195 & 2500 & 3,8 \\
1929 & 74200 & 3100 & 4,0 \\
1930 & 59346 & 2800 & 4,5 \\
\addlinespace
1935 & 31030 & 1516 & 4,7 \\
1936 & 49398 & 2268 & 4,4 \\
1937 & 72808 & 2481 & 3,3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

When processed with:

```
htlatex document.tex "xhtml,ooffice" " -cmozhtf" " -coo"
```

it outputs a document. But the place where the table lies turns into a "box" in the .odt output, and the file ends there.

As a matter of fact, the .odt is corrupt. LibreOffice opens it and doesn't complain, but unpacking the .odt the `contents.xml` is invalid and ends somewhere along the table.

It is enough to load makecell to reproduce the problem (even without using its macros, as long as there is a table).

Any thoughts on this? Better leave `makecell`? Or is there a way to work this out?

Comment: I guess that `makecell` redefines internal LaTeX macros for table handling, which breaks `tex4ht` table support. I will look at this issue later.

Comment: @michal.h21 That's what I suppose too. I have been trying other similar constructs, and e.g. [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678/105447) nesting tabulars, which doesn't break the final result, but also doesn't show up in it.

Comment: There are several problems. First is that `makecell` really breaks something with `tex4ht`, the second is that there was wrong detection of tables nested inside other tables in tex4ht, the third is that LibreOffice doesn't seem to like nested tables. I need to investigate it moe.

Comment: @michal.h21 I thank you very much if you do so. From my point of view, there is no real need to "fix" the relation of `makecell` and `tex4ht` (though that might be useful from a general point of view). If there's something reasonable that substitutes its function, I'd be already very glad. What I'm trying to do at the moment is to devise a LaTeX workflow that also leaves me with an .odt when needed. So I'm mapping what of the usual features I employ in LaTeX actually work with `tex4ht` (This means I may come up with more stuff this week).

Comment: I've found that `Makecell` really breaks tex4ht, but it should be possible just normal nested tabulars, it is only necessary to edit the XML file, using `make4ht` script

Comment: @michal.h21 An answer in these lines would be very welcome.

Comment: it seems that the table inside another table breaks the `ODT` output, regardless of the `Makecell` package. It works in the HTML output, so there must be some configuration issue, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. First one is a wrong configuration for the `array` package, which is required by `makecell`. It somehow breaks the default configuration for tabular in the `ooffice` output. The offending code is a following snippet:

```
\ifTag{vis-\TableNo-\HRow}%                                                                                                                                                                                  
      {\special{t4ht@[}\gdef\end:box{\special{t4ht@]}}}%                                                                                                                                                     
      {\global\let\end:box\empty}%
```

The `\ifTag` command checks a existence of cross-reference defined in the `.xref` file - `tex4ht` keeps stuff like hyperlinks and other information needed between compilations. The code

```
 {\special{t4ht@[}\gdef\end:box{\special{t4ht@]}}}%
```

is executed on the next and following compilations after the table have been added to the document. It disables processing of characters and spaces using `\special{t4ht@[}`, their processing is enabled with `\special{t4ht@]}`,  which is executed in `\end:box` macro. The problem is that the instruction `\special{t4ht@]}` is inserted one more time somewhere in the process. This causes `tex4ht` to immediately stop the output, so the XML file stops inside the table and rest of the document is omitted. The XML file is of course invalid. It all happens only at second and subsequent compilations, not on the first  one, which makes it even harder to trace source of this issue.

I don't really know why this whole thing is used anyway, I cannot see a difference when it is omitted. I hope it is safe to delete it. Because `ooffice.4ht` is huge, I will post only needed patch here:

```
--- /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht   2018-06-08 00:41:40.000000000 +0200
+++ makecell/ooffice.4ht    2018-06-15 14:24:09.787127871 +0200
@@ -1794,8 +1794,9 @@
 %
    }
    {\HCode{</table:table>}}
-   {\ifTag{vis-\TableNo-\HRow}%
-      {\special{t4ht@[}\gdef\end:box{\special{t4ht@]}}}%
+   {
+%\ifTag{vis-\TableNo-\HRow}%
+      %{\special{t4ht@[}\gdef\end:box{\special{t4ht@]}}}%
       {\global\let\end:box\empty}%
 %
     \HCode{<table:table-row \Hnewline
```

The second issue is that the subtables inserted by `makecell` are places inside paragraphs, which is not supported  by the ODT format. It is hard to fix that using just macros, it is better to use a  `make4ht` filter.

File `mybuild.mk4`:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local process = domfilter {
  function(dom)
    -- process all tables which are child nodes of text:p element, which is forbidden
    for _, table in ipairs(dom:query_selector("text|p table|table")) do
      print "*******************************************"
      -- replace the text:p with table:table
      local parent = table:get_parent()
      parent:replace_node(table)
      print(parent:get_parent():serialize())
    end
    return dom
  end
}

Make:match("4oo", process)
```

Note that the development version of `make4ht`, not the version on CTAN is needed. Compile using:

```
make4ht -e mybuild.mk4 -f odt filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Wow!! Impressive! That was a tricky one, eh! :) Thank you very, very much!

Comment: thanks, it was indeed mysterious issue and hard to identify