# Line break in table (math-mode)

Tags: tables, math-mode, line-breaking

How can I add a line break into a table during math-mode?
For instance, here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|l}
1&1&1&$X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X$
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use, for instance `\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|p{10cm}}` instead...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That doesn't work, I am sorry.

Comment: @JasperHabicht It's not a duplicate because I want to find a solution for math-mode. :(

Comment: @user372565 Then please explain _how_ my suggestion doesn't work and how do _you_ expect it to work.

Comment: @user372565 if you use a `p` column as suggested in the comment you will need `$x\otimes....$` in the cell  (or use `array` package `>{$}p{10cm}<{$}` )

Comment: Note that if you code `X^{\otimes 25}`,  you won't need any line break ;o)