# How to modify chronosys \chronoperiode and \chronoevent?

Tags: chronosys

I am using Latex Beamer to create a short biography using `\chronology`. I am trying to have multiple lines in `chroneperiode` and `chronevent`. Also, when I add a `chroneevent`, I am trying to remove the year from the timeline and only have one year. Finally, I am trying to cover partial timeline. For instance, I graduated in August 2010, so I want colored bar to reach 8/12 of the year.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{chronosys}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{84CECC}
\definecolor{gr}{HTML}{375D81}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Biographical Sketch}
\textbf{Education}

\startchronology[align=left, startyear=2002,stopyear=2015, height=0pt, startdate=false, stopdate=false, dateselevation=0pt, arrow=false, box=true]
%
\chronograduation[event][dateselevation=0pt]{1}

\chronoperiode[textstyle=\raggedleft\colorbox{gr!50}, color=gr, startdate=false, bottomdepth=0pt, topheight=10pt, textdepth=-20pt,dateselevation=16pt, datesseparation=/,conversionmonth=true,stopdate=false]{2003}{2007}{\begin{scriptsize} BSC Unib. \end{scriptsize}}

\chronoevent[textstyle=\raggedleft\colorbox{gr!50}, color=gr, startdate=false, bottomdepth=30pt, topheight=10pt, year=true, textdepth=-40pt,dateselevation=16pt, datesseparation=/,conversionmonth=false,topdate=false]{2007}{\begin{tiny}B.Sc. in XX \end{tiny}}

\chronoperiode[textstyle=\colorbox{blue!50}, color=blue, startdate=false, bottomdepth=0pt, topheight=10pt, textdepth=-20pt,dateselevation=16pt, stopdate=false]{2008}{2010}{\begin{scriptsize}M.S. Univ.\end{scriptsize}}

\chronoevent[textstyle=\raggedleft\colorbox{blue!50}, color=blue, startdate=false, bottomdepth=30pt, topheight=10pt, year=true, textdepth=-10pt,dateselevation=16pt, datesseparation=/,conversionmonth=false,stopdate=false]{2010}{\begin{tiny}M.S. in X Field.\end{tiny}}

\chronoperiode[textstyle=\colorbox{red!50}, color=red, startdate=false, bottomdepth=0pt, topheight=10pt, textdepth=-20pt,dateselevation=16pt, stopdate=false]{2010}{2014}{\begin{scriptsize}Doctoral Univ.\end{scriptsize}}
\stopchronology

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the line breaking one workaround is to define a macro like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678/586, and use that in the labels.