# How to use \thead with left align locally instead of globally?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, alignment, makecell

How to align the contents of the `\thead` cell to the right?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \thead{Content \\ Other alignment}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I know I can globally override all `\thead` environments alignment with something line `\renewcommand\theadalign{ll}`. Is there another way other than globally overriding all `\thead` environments alignment, i.e., doing it only for one cell?

1. [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by specifying that option in `\thead`. Such as `\thead[r]`, `\thead[l]`, `\thead[c]`, etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \thead[l]{Content \\ Other alignment}\\
        \hline
        \thead[c]{Content \\ Other alignment}\\
        \hline
        \thead[r]{Content \\ Other alignment}\\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `\thead[l]{...}` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \thead[l]{Content \\ Other alignment} &
    \thead[r]{Content \\ Other alignment} &
    \thead[t]{Content \\ Other alignment} &
    \thead[b]{Content \\ Other alignment}         
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```