# rowcolor uneffective in longtable with makecell

Tags: longtable, rowcolor, makecell

I'm trying to color the rows of a `longtable` with `rowcolor` as follow (in the MWE I have onyl included few rows of the very long table):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=8pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
bottom=22mm,
top=22mm,
left=15mm,
right=15mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\definecolor{colorA}{rgb}{29,140,118}
\definecolor{colorB}{rgb}{251,174,62}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\begin{document}
{\scriptsize\tabcolsep=2pt
    \centering
    \begin{longtable}[c]{@{}cccccccccccc@{}} 
        \caption*{\textbf{Supplementary table 2}. DEGs summary} \\ \midrule
        \thead{xxxxx} & \thead{yyyyy} & \thead{xxxxx\\yyyyy} & \thead{xxxxx\\yyyyy} & \thead{yyyyy} & \thead{xxxxx\\yyyyy} & \thead{xxxxx\\yyyyy} & \thead{xxxxx} & \thead{xxxxx\\yyyyy} & \thead{xxxxx\\yyyyy} & \thead{xxxxx\\yyyyy} & \thead{xxxxx\\yyyyy} \\ \midrule
        \rowcolor{colorA} 
        0dk2 & 651,3505 & -1,1010 & 0,1016 & -10,8339 & 0,0000 & 0,0000 & 0,0156 & 0,0003 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \rowcolor{colorA}  
        AABR07001896.1 & 29,4550 & -1,0138 & 0,2150 & -4,7147 & 0,0000 & 0,0001 & 0,0391 & 0,0003 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        \rowcolor{colorB} 
        AABR07001905.1 & 23,0908 & -1,2473 & 0,3169 & -3,9357 & 0,0001 & 0,0011 & 0,1166 & 0,0020 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        \rowcolor{colorB} 
        AABR07001910.1 & 30,9100 & -1,7463 & 0,3645 & -4,7906 & 0,0000 & 0,0000 & 0,1770 & 0,0003 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        \rowcolor{colorA} 
        AABR07001923.1 & 21,8214 & -1,5873 & 0,2611 & -6,0797 & 0,0000 & 0,0000 & 0,0528 & 0,0003 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

However the rows do not get colored:
[image: output example]

I suspect that the problems comes from the fact that I use the `makecell` command. I cannot get rid of it because I need to force line breaks in the headings of the table as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell/19678).

I've looked at the other issues with `rowcolor` and `longtable` here but they do not seem to be related with mine.

Comment: Hey, with e.g. `red` as colour it works (if you want to colour the whole line), I think the error lies within the defined colour, although I can't point exactly where. Edit: Is it possible, that the rgb values should be fractions of 1, e.g. `\definecolor{colorA}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}` (although this is not the colour you want)

Comment: yes that was the answer. Thanks! So silly from me. If you post it as an aswer I will flag it as correct

Comment: If you want to keep your color definitions with their current values, just replace `rgb` with `RGB`.

Comment: thanks @leandriis, thats good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out below the problem lies with the fact that rgb values should be fractions of 1. Or alternatively, to use these color definition `rgb` must be replaced with `RGB`