# Align table heading at the top of the table

Tags: line-breaking, headline

I have a problem with the alignment of the heading in my table. Here I want to force a line break with the function `\shortstack` for the table headers. This works also so far.
However, I would like to align the heading to the top of the table. I have not found a working alternative for the `\shortstack`-function yet.

Solutions are offered here, but for some reason they do not work in my case:
[How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell/19678)

Can someone help me to align the headers to the top?
(And possibly left-aligned in addition?)

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow} \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top} \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} \usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx} \newcolumntype{d}{S[table-format=2.1]}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {>{\raggedright}l|d|dddd}
\toprule
\shortstack{CAAR\\Window} & \shortstack{All\\transaction\\forms} & \shortstack{Acquisition Of\\ Partial Interest} & \shortstack{Acquisition Of\\ Majority Assets} &  \shortstack{Acquisition Of \\ Remaining Interest} & \shortstack{Merger}\\
\midrule
{(-15,-2)} & 1.7*** & 1.3** & 1.8** & 2.2*** & 2.0***\\
{(-10,-1)} & 1.9*** & 0.9** & 2.2*** & 2.4*** & 2.5***\\
{(-5,-1)} & 1.3*** & 0.9*** & 1.2*** & 1.4*** & 1.7***\\
{(-5,+5)} & 13.3*** & 5.7*** & 12.2*** & 14.7*** & 20.9***\\
{(-2,+2)} & 12.6*** & 5.5*** & 11.1*** & 13.8*** & 19.9***\\
{(-1,+1)} & 11.8*** & 5.0*** & 9.8*** & 11.9*** & 19.4***\\
{(0,0)} & 8.7*** & 3.0*** & 6.3*** & 7.0*** & 16.0***\\
{(0,+10)} & 12.1*** & 4.9*** & 10.7*** & 13.5*** & 19.4***\\
{(1,+10)} & 3.4*** & 1.8*** & 4.4*** & 6.5*** & 3.5***\\
{(2,+15)} & 1.2*** & 0.4 & 1.6** & 2.1*** & 1.4***\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I already used the `\thead` and the `\makecell`-function , but the table heading is shifted strangely:

[image]

Comment: Did you try with the `\thead` command, from `makecell`? The default alignment is centred both vertically  and horizeontally, but you can change it with an optional argument. In your case, if I understand well what you want, `\thead[tc]{…}` would do it – if it is compatible with `tabu`.

Comment: Yes I've tried the `\thead[tc]{…}`- command, but the table heading is shifted strangely. See my edit.

Comment: Or maybe, add an empty third row to the  `\shortstack`s with only two rows?

Comment: Good idea. But `\shortstack{CAAR\\Window \\ { }` gives me a centered aligned heading not a top aligned.

Comment: And with a `\phantom{A}` in the third row?

Comment: Yes. This could be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I wouldn't use package `tabu`. It is not maintained anymore, regardless that exist some fixes for its non-combability with new version of the `array` package, it is not recommended to use.
- In your case I will rather use `tabularx`
- for aligning of numbers I would use `S` column type defined in the `siunitx` package
- It is sufficient, that you load each package only once :-), also is sensible to group packages according to their use (see MWE below)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{mO{C}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{table-format=2.1,
             table-space-text-post={***}
             } 
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells 
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}r<{$}@{\,}>{$}l<{$} | S | *{4}{S} @{}}
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\mcc{2}[c|]{\makecell[t]{CAAR\\Window}} 
    & \mcc{1}[c|]{\makecell[t]{All\\transaction\\forms}} 
        & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of\\ Partial Interest}} 
            & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of\\ Majority Assets}} 
                &  \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of \\ Remaining Interest}} 
                    & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Merger}}\\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
(-15,   & -2)   &  1.7*** & 1.3**  &  1.8**  &  2.2*** &  2.0***    \\
(-10,   & -1)   &  1.9*** & 0.9**  &  2.2*** &  2.4*** &  2.5***    \\
 (-5,   & -1)   &  1.3*** & 0.9*** &  1.2*** &  1.4*** &  1.7***    \\
 (-5,   & +5)   & 13.3*** & 5.7*** & 12.2*** & 14.7*** & 20.9***    \\
 (-2,   & +2)   & 12.6*** & 5.5*** & 11.1*** & 13.8*** & 19.9***    \\
 (-1,   & +1)   & 11.8*** & 5.0*** &  9.8*** & 11.9*** & 19.4***    \\
  (0,   & 0)    &  8.7*** & 3.0*** &  6.3*** &  7.0*** & 16.0***    \\
  (0,   & +10)  & 12.1*** & 4.9*** & 10.7*** & 13.5*** & 19.4***    \\
  (1,   & +10)  &  3.4*** & 1.8*** &  4.4*** &  6.5*** &  3.5***    \\
  (2,   & +15)  &  1.2*** & 0.4    &  1.6**  &  2.1*** &  1.4***    \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You not only control the alignment to the decimal points, but also the alignment to the coma in the first column. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is those `d` columns, I believe --- change them to `l` using `\multicolumn`, and `\makecell` will work:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow} \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top} \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} \usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx} \newcolumntype{d}{S[table-format=2.1]}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {>{\raggedright}l|d|dddd}
\toprule
\multicolumn1{l|}{\makecell[t]{CAAR\\Window}} & \multicolumn1{l|}{\makecell[t]{All\\transaction\\forms}} & \multicolumn1l{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of\\ Partial Interest}} & \multicolumn1l{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of\\ Majority Assets}} &  \multicolumn1l{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of \\ Remaining Interest}} & \multicolumn1l{\makecell[t]{Merger}}\\
\midrule
{(-15,-2)} & 1.7*** & 1.3** & 1.8** & 2.2*** & 2.0***\\
{(-10,-1)} & 1.9*** & 0.9** & 2.2*** & 2.4*** & 2.5***\\
{(-5,-1)} & 1.3*** & 0.9*** & 1.2*** & 1.4*** & 1.7***\\
{(-5,+5)} & 13.3*** & 5.7*** & 12.2*** & 14.7*** & 20.9***\\
{(-2,+2)} & 12.6*** & 5.5*** & 11.1*** & 13.8*** & 19.9***\\
{(-1,+1)} & 11.8*** & 5.0*** & 9.8*** & 11.9*** & 19.4***\\
{(0,0)} & 8.7*** & 3.0*** & 6.3*** & 7.0*** & 16.0***\\
{(0,+10)} & 12.1*** & 4.9*** & 10.7*** & 13.5*** & 19.4***\\
{(1,+10)} & 3.4*** & 1.8*** & 4.4*** & 6.5*** & 3.5***\\
{(2,+15)} & 1.2*** & 0.4 & 1.6** & 2.1*** & 1.4***\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works!