# How to force space in table environment?

Tags: tables, spacing, line-breaking

I have a table with the following row:

[image]

Currently, 'SVM' and 'RF' are shown next to each other in the 'Algorithm' column. Instead, I want RF to be shown underneath in the same row. I tried to do this by using spaces, but that doesnt work. How can I force the spaces? Or is there another way to do this?

I have the following code:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{0.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.2cm}|p{0.8cm}| }
 \hline
 &F1&Prec.&Recall&Task&Training set&Algorithm&Representation&Year\\
 \hline
 \cite{zhu2020comparisons}&0.989, 0.989&0.996, 0.998&0.982, 0.980&Symptoms&2000&SVM, RF&TF&2020\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [MWE?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Hi Thruston, I have just added a MWE

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2442/250119

Comment: Why don't you create a new row for the second line?