# Line-breaking table column with adaptive width

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I'd like to have a table column with the following properties

- allow text with explicit linebreaks
- automatically break long lines at a maximum width
- only extend column width to minimal necessary width

I have tried the following

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
1 & tabular l \\
\hline
 & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} short first line \\ short second line \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
2 & tabular l \\
\hline
 & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} short first line \\ long second line which definitely needs a line break otherwise it runs off the page completely which would be a shame \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l|p{0.6\textwidth}}
3 & tabular p \\
\hline
 & short first line \newline short second line
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l|p{0.6\textwidth}}
4 & tabular p \\
\hline
 & short first line \newline long second line which definitely needs a line break otherwise it runs off the page completely which would be a shame
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{l|X}
5 & tabulary X \\
\hline
 & short first line \newline short second line
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{l|X}
6 & tabulary X \\
\hline
 & short first line \newline long second line which definitely needs a line break otherwise it runs off the page completely which would be a shame
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The desired appearance is like example 1 for the short/short lines

[image]

and like example 4 for the short/long lines

[image]

however, each of my methods only work for either the short/short or short/long case, but never both:
example 2 runs off the page, and example 3/5 make the column unnecessarily wide.

Comment: If you are looking for the " jack of all trades" for tables, I recommend the [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. For example is provides the varwidth library for columns with line breaks and automatic width. Nevertheless, I have my doubts that the same column specification can be the best one for all types of content.

Comment: probably tabulary does what you want but I don't really understand your example with nested one column `tabular` where you are explicitly stopping line breaking by using a single column table withan `l` column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the nested `tabular` is a workaround to add forced line breaks into an `l` column, copied from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678/314131)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer of DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709580/314131) was almost there, but needed a little tweak.
The column in the short/short case was still too wide due to how `tabulary` calculates render width.

I fixed this by replacing the manual `\linebreak` inside a single cell by rendering each line in a separate row, like this

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|l|J|}
1 & tabulary J \\
\hline
 & short first line \\
 & short second line
\end{tabulary}

\bigskip

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|l|J|}
2 & tabulary J \\
\hline
 & short first line \\
 & long second line which definitely needs a line break otherwise it runs off the page completely which would be a shame
\end{tabulary}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result is then as desired in all cases:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`tabulary` (by default) does not extend the table to the target width if it is naturally smaller

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|l|J|}
1 & tabular l \\
\hline
 & short first line \newline short second line
\end{tabulary}

\bigskip

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|l|J|}
2 & tabular l \\
\hline
 & short first line \newline long second line which definitely needs a line break otherwise it runs off the page completely which would be a shame
\end{tabulary}

\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is going in the right direction! Thanks for pointing out the `J` column type. The column in your example 1 still extends quite beyond what would be necessary for holding the two short lines (compare it to example 1 in the question). Do you know why this is the case and how to make it really the minimal necessary width?

Comment: @Pybe tabulary has a parameter to set the minimum width of columns (to prevent it scrunching up whole paragraphs into columns 1 letter wide) but you can reduce it see the package doc.

Comment: I checked the [docs](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabulary/tabulary.pdf), but couldn't get `tymin` to work. Also, it seems connected to `\newline` - the final width of the column seems roughly the length of text without manual line break. If I put the two lines in separate rows `& short first line \\ & short second line`, the width is correct. Can I maybe add a new line differently so `tabulary` can infer the correct minimal width over all lines?

Comment: @Pybe ah you are probably right, I wrote TY over a couple of weekends last century sometime: I may have forgotten some details:-) its measure of how much content a column has does, as you see, involve a first pass setting everything on one line.

Comment: I solved it using the workaround above: instead of `\newline` I create line breaks by writing into additional rows. Should I add this to your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Pybe or post (and accept) a complete answer yourself leaving this as the basic hint (I really can live without the 15 pt for a green tick, thanks:-)