How to produce this table: Probability datatable with multirow
I want to produce the the following table:

This is my working(only data for Male)
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.7cm}|}\\ \cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{Exact age}  &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{male}\\ \cline{2-4} 
                        & Death probability & Number of lives  & Life expectancy\\ \cline{1-4}
0                       & 0.007589      & 100,000       & 73.98\\ \cline{1-4}
1                       & 0.000543      & 99,241            & 73.54 \\ \cline{1-4}
2                       & 0.000376      & 99,187            & 72.58 \\ \cline{1-4}                      
\end{tabular}

And this is what I get:

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Note: I'm not interested in thick lines or footnotes.

The first \ causes the stray lines at the top.

You're right. That was the first culprit. Thank you for the fast comment.

This is a side note. It is unrelated to the present post.
To the nice people who keep upvoting me because I visit
this golden website and its brother MSE so many times a
day. If I do so, that's because it is part of the process of
my learning. And I'm not fishing for any reputation.
Anyway thanks a lot for your warm encouragements.

@Rafiq You completely changed your question... the answers obviously don't address this new question. Reverse to your inital question and create a new one.

If you don't mind using the tabularray package, things are really easy

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Q[c] Q[c] Q[c] l},
  cell{1}{2} = {c=3}{c},
  hline{1,3} = {-}{},
  hline{2} = {2-4}{},
}
  {Exact\\age} & {male} & & \\
  & {Death\\probability} & {Number\\of lives} & {Life\\expectancy} \\
  0 & \num{0.007589} & \num{100000} & \num{73.98} \\
  1 & \num{0.000543} & \num{99241} & \num{73.54} \\
  2 & \num{0.000376} & \num{99187} & \num{72.58} \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

and with the booktabs options with tabularray

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Q[c] Q[c] Q[c] l},
  cell{1}{2} = {c=3}{c},
  hline{2} = {2-4}{},
}
\toprule
  {Exact\\age} & {male} & & \\
  & {Death\\probability} & {Number\\of lives} & {Life\\expectancy} \\
\midrule
  0 & \num{0.007589} & \num{100000} & \num{73.98} \\
  1 & \num{0.000543} & \num{99241} & \num{73.54} \\
  2 & \num{0.000376} & \num{99187} & \num{72.58} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


Thanks @Jet. Now I'm focusing to learn tables as best as I could.

then spend time on tabularray :)

I'll do. Be sure of that.

Following the kind comment by Zarko, I accept your answer. The other answers are also beneficial to me.

As commented, the first \\ causes the extra vertical lines.  Also, \cline{1-4} is equivalent to \hline, which better describes how you're using it.
But I would redesign the table a bit.  The first thing is to use booktabs and take its advice: vertical lines kill puppies, and horizontal lines are usually unnecessary (more seriously, lines should not be necessary to help interpret the data in a table, and can actually hinder interpretation).  We can also use siunitx to have it format the numbers and line things up nicely.  (And to keep the line breaks, we'll use \specialcell from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678/107497).  I end up with:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
S[table-format=1]
 S[table-format=1.6]
  S[table-format=6]
   S[table-format=2.2]}\toprule
{\multirow{2}{*}{\specialcell{Exact\\age}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{male}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-4}
    & {\specialcell{Death\\probability}}
    & {\specialcell{Number\\of lives}}
    & {\specialcell{Life\\expectancy}} \\ \midrule
0   & 0.007589      & 100000     & 73.98 \\
1   & 0.000543      & 99241      & 73.54 \\
2   & 0.000376      & 99187      & 72.58 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

which renders as

When you go to include females, you'll want to change the \cmidrule(l) to (lr).  And as a bonus, this table is a little more compact (although that is mostly due to new linebreaks in the first and last columns).

Thanks for your answer. I'll take your advice into account. I struggled a lot with this table.

One more solution using tabularray package. In it is employed siunitx package for defining column types and tblr-extras for defining caption style using caption package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}    %%%% new, it works with recent version   
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                caption,
                siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=1ex,
                     font = {small, sf},
                     labelfont = bf,
                     justification=centerlast
                    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {This table is about something},
  label = {tblr:something},
 note{} = {DP: Death probability;\quad
           NL: Number of lives;\quad
           LE: Life expectancy}
                ]{colspec = {Q[c, si={table-format=1}]
                             *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.6}] 
                                  Q[c, si={table-format=7}]
                                  Q[c, si={table-format=2.2}]}
                            },
                  cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
                  cell{1}{2,5} = {c=3}{},
                  row{1,2}  = {guard}
                  }
    \toprule
{Exact\\age} 
    &   Male    &           &           &   Female  &           &       \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
    \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
    &   DL      & NL        &   LE      &   DL      & NL        &   LE  \\
    \midrule
 0 & 0.007589   & 100000    & 73.98     & 0.007589  & 100000    & 73.98 \\
 1 & 0.000543   &  99241    & 73.54     & 0.000543  &  99241    & 73.54 \\
 2 & 0.000376   &  99187    & 72.58     & 0.000376  &  99187    & 72.58 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}



Thanks for promoting my small package

@Mane32, your are welcome. Your package is excellent.  Now I use it at talltblr and longtblr regularly. Thank you for for it!

@Mane32 i'll follow zarko on this. Thank you.

A suggestion with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\Block[t]{2-1}{Exact\\ age} & \Block{1-3}{male} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& \Block{}{Death\\probability} & \Block{}{Number\\ of lives} & \Block{}{Life\\ expectancy} \\
\midrule
0 & \num{0.007589} & \num{100000} & \num{73.98} \\
1 & \num{0.000543} & \num{99241} & \num{73.54} \\
2 & \num{0.000376} & \num{99187} & \num{72.58} \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}



Thanks for sharing with me a little knowledge. I hope I could soon be able to learn fast, and absorb a great quantity.

If you really like caged tables:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.7cm}|}\\ \cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{Exact age}  &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{male}\\ \cline{2-4} 
                        & Death probability & Number of lives  & Life expectancy\\ \cline{1-4}
0                       & 0.007589      & 100,000       & 73.98\\ \cline{1-4}
1                       & 0.000543      & 99,241            & 73.54 \\ \cline{1-4}
2                       & 0.000376      & 99,187            & 72.58 \\ \cline{1-4}                      
\end{tabular}

Using a legend, the size of the columns can be kept tight.

An open look is, in my opinion, much better.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\sisetup{
  group-digits=integer,
  group-separator={,},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
 @{}
 c
 S[table-format=1.6]
 S[table-format=6.0]
 S[table-format=2.2]
 S[table-format=1.6]
 S[table-format=6.0]
 S[table-format=2.2]
 @{}
}
\toprule
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Exact \\ age\end{tabular}}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Male}
& \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Female} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& {DP} & {NL} & {LE} & {DP} & {NL} & {LE} \\
\midrule
0 & 0.007589 & 100000 & 73.98 & 0.007589 & 100000 & 73.98 \\
1 & 0.000543 &  99241 & 73.54 & 0.000543 &  99241 & 73.54 \\
2 & 0.000376 &  99187 & 72.58 & 0.000376 &  99187 & 72.58 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l@{}}{%
  \footnotesize
  DP: Death probability;\quad
  NL: Number of lives;\quad
  LE: Life expectancy%
}
\end{tabular}

\caption{This table is about something}

\end{table}

\end{document}



Thank you so much for your invaluable help and for all your contributions.

From all the answers I got, now I Know how a professional table must be made. That said, I kept asking how did my book make that original one. And I figured out.
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}\cline{1-7}
&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{male} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Female}\\ \cline{2-7}
Exact &Death      &Number & Life            &Death      &Number & Life\\ 
age   &probability & of lives  & expectancy & probability & of lives & expectancy   \\ \cline{1-7}
0      & 0.007589 & 100,000 & 73.98      & 0.006234  & 100,000 & 79.35      \\ \cline{1-7}
1     & 0.000543  & 99,241   & 73.54         & 0.000447  & 99,377   & 78.84         \\ \cline{1-7}
2    &  0.000376  & 99,187   & 72.58         & 0.000376  & 99,187   & 72.58          \\ \cline{1-7}
\end{tabular}


to get rid of some horizontal lines, some c lines must be deleted
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}\cline{1-7}
&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{male} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Female}\\ \cline{2-7}
Exact &Death      &Number & Life            &Death      &Number & Life\\ 
age   &probability & of lives  & expectancy & probability & of lives & expectancy   \\ \cline{1-7}
0      & 0.007589 & 100,000 & 73.98      & 0.006234  & 100,000 & 79.35      \\ 
1     & 0.000543  & 99,241   & 73.54         & 0.000447  & 99,377   & 78.84         \\ 
2    &  0.000376  & 99,187   & 72.58         & 0.000376  & 99,187   & 72.58          \\ \cline{1-7}
\end{tabular}



Hm, table design as proposed in other answers are more appealing and with much clearer code. You should consider to accept one of them.

How could I accept one of them. They're all so good to me!

Simple, select one, which you the most liked. Until you will not accept one, your question will treat  as unsolved ...

I just did. See the first answer. Thank you.
