# Formatting table

Tags: tables

I have a table that is created with the following code:

```
\begin{table}[htdp]
\caption{Comparison of Elements in Air on the Space Station and sea level on Earth}    
\centering
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Chemical Component & Percentage in Earth's Atomsphere & Ideal Values for the Space Station &         Astronaut Exhalation\\ \hline
Nitrogen      & 78.084\% & 78.000\% & 74.200\% \\ \hline
Oxygen        & 20.946\% & 21.000\% & 15.300\% \\ \hline
Argon         & 0.934\%  &  0.000\% & 0.000\% \\ \hline
Carbon Dioxide& 0.033\%  &  0.000\% & 3.600\% \\ \hline
Water Vapour  & 0.030\%  &  1.000\% & 0.800\% \\ \hline
Trace Elements& 0.003\%  &  0.000\% & 0.800\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{default}
\end{table}
```

But it sticks over the page so how could i format it so that it fits on a page in portrait mode not landscape.

Comment: FYI, you don't need both the `center` environment and the `\centering` command. The latter is the recommended way to center the content of your float.

Comment: Ok ive used `\centering`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\Centering}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htdp]
\caption{Comparison of Elements in Air on the Space Station and sea level on Earth}\label{default}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm}|x|x|x|}\hline
Chemical Component & Percentage in Earth's Atomsphere & Ideal Values for the Space Station & Astronaut Exhalation\\ \hline
Nitrogen      & 78.084\% & 78.000\% & 74.200\% \\ \hline
Oxygen        & 20.946\% & 21.000\% & 15.300\% \\ \hline
Argon         & 0.934\%  &  0.000\% &  0.000\% \\ \hline
Carbon Dioxide& 0.033\%  &  0.000\% &  3.600\% \\ \hline
Water Vapour  & 0.030\%  &  1.000\% &  0.800\% \\ \hline
Trace Elements& 0.003\%  &  0.000\% &  0.800\% \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

btw: the vertical lines do not make a table more readable ...

Comment: Same for the horizontal. Stick to 1 or 2 maximum.

Check http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables for more info on this.

Answer (score 8):

To learn about table design in general, I cannot praise the documentation of the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) package enough (see a before-and-after example from the documentation below). For your problem at hand, I would suggest to either come up with shorter column titles or to break them into several lines. This problem has been discussed as [How to break a line in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-break-a-line-in-a-table).

[image: Example from the booktabs package about table design]

In [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12213/formatting-table/12219#12219) [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) has formatted the table from the question using the `booktabs` package and solved the problem how to break the column titles into two lines. I find it close to perfection.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `array` package to have better control over table column specifications. Your problem is caused by the length of your column headings; you need to have specified widths but still centred titles.  It's generally not advisable to have vertical lines in tables, nor to put the units (here '%') in each cell (they should go in the column heading).  Given that all your numeric values are decimals, you also want to line up the decimal points.  A right justified column can do this, but the `dcolumn` package provides more flexibility.  As Christian mentions, the `booktabs package is the gold standard here.

Here's a version of your table using these principles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2.3}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering}p}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htdp]
\caption{Comparison of Elements in Air on the Space Station and sea level on Earth}    
\centering
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.25in}ddd}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.25in}}{Chemical Component} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1in}}{Earth's Atmosphere (\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.25in}}{Ideal Values for the Space Station (\%)} &         \multicolumn{1}{C{1in}}{Astronaut Exhalation (\%)}\\
\midrule
Nitrogen & 78.084 & 78.000 & 74.200 \\
Oxygen & 20.946 & 21.000 & 15.300 \\
Argon & 0.934 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
Carbon Dioxide & 0.033 & 0.000 & 3.600 \\
Water Vapour & 0.030 & 1.000 & 0.800 \\
Trace Elements & 0.003 & 0.000 & 0.800 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{default}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Nice! A minor suggestion: The `booktabs` package recommends putting the units into the column titles (rather than into the rows). I get the feeling that the values for the space station and the astronauts suggest a precision that isn't there and would recommend (to the author) using fewer digits.

Comment: @Christian I agree with booktabs on this, but in this particular case I couldn't find any nice way to put the '%' in the heading without making the table look really ugly, so this was the best compromise.  I might be inclined to have simply put a comment in the caption "All values are percentages" intstead.

Comment: @Christian If I make the middle column a little wider it's not so ugly.  I've updated my answer. (P.S. I agree with the precision comment as well.)

Answer (score 5):

I could feel my `\halign`-sense tingling. Mainly to highlight one other  recommendation; to always left-align everything (or at least give you an idea how'd that look). But also the other option of splitting the column-heading row to two rows. It might not feel such a good idea, but the one thing going for it, is the lack of manually declared column widths. I should probably point out that some of the following is borderline heresy.

```
\vbox{\openup.4em% make the row separating space a bit bigger
  \def\title#1&{\omit#1\hfil&}% omit the preamble formatting + left-align
  \def\decsplit#1.#2 {\quad\llap{#1}.\rlap{#2}}% quad = 2*enspace; enspace = digit width
  % only thing "seen" is the decimal point itself
  \hrule height 1pt \medskip
  \halign{#\hfil\tabskip1em&&\decsplit#\hfil\cr
    \title Chemical&\title Earth's&\title Ideal Values for the&\title Astronaut\cr
    \noalign{\vskip-.4em}% make the gap between header rows smaller
    \title Component&\title Athmosphere (\%)&\title Space Station (\%)&\title Exhalation (\%)\cr
    \noalign{\smallskip\hrule\medskip}
    Nitrogen      &78.084 &78.000 &74.200 \cr
    Oxygen        &20.946 &21.000 &15.300 \cr
    Argon         & 0.934 & 0.000 & 0.000 \cr
    Carbon Dioxide& 0.033 & 0.000 & 3.600 \cr
    Water Vapour  & 0.030 & 1.000 & 0.800 \cr
    Trace Elements& 0.003 & 0.000 & 0.800 \cr
  }
  \medskip
  \hrule height 1pt
}
```

[image: halign]

Comment: It's probably worth going with the defaults for rule width and spacing given in `booktabs`. I.e., something like `\kern\abovetopsep \hrule height\heavyrulewidth \kern\belowrulesep` for the top rule, `\kern\aboverulesep \hrule height\lightrulewidth \kern\belowrulesep` for the middle rule, and `\kern\aboverulesep \hrule height\heavyrulewidth \kern\belowbottomsep` for the bottom rule. Replacing those dimensions as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You should stack the long cell titles e.g. by manually placing them over several rows or using `\shortstack`:

```
\shortstack{Ideal Values\\for the\\Space Station}
```

You might want to add a `\strut` to the `\\` to get a constant distance between the lines.