# Add notes under the table

Tags: tables, notes

I'm using the latex package [`apa6e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa6e) because the [`apa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa) package isn't using APA style version 6 yet.

Now I'm trying to add a table with notes right underneath it, like in this table for instance:

[image: Example Table]

Since the `\caption{}` is used as a title above the table, I have to add an extra row for the notes that goes over the whole table width. The problem is that the notes won't fit into one line so I need multi-line cell. How can I accomplish that? Or am I doing it totally wrong and there is a much easier way? I guess footnotes don't work here.

```
\documentclass{apa6e}

\begin{document}
\shorttitle{}
\begin{table}
\caption{title}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
foo & bar\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Notes. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lacus orci, porttitor et posuere sit amet, tempor non justo. Ut quis aliquet turpis. Ut dictum nulla eget purus elementum a lacinia libero varius. Donec malesuada nulla ut odio rhoncus convallis. Aenean faucibus sollicitudin sapien, a vestibulum ante rhoncus sit amet. In vitae mi justo. In arcu metus, porta et lacinia ut, ultricies sed eros.}
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could simply use a `p` cell to get the content wrapped, such as `\multicolumn{2}{p{.8\textwidth}}{Notes. Lorem ipsum ...}`.

Comment: For this particular use (i.e. a general note) the comments above are adequate.  For proper footnotes in tables you should probably use the [`threeparttable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package. You should also probably be using the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package.  See this answer to this question: [Formatting table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12213/formatting-table/12217#12217)

Answer (score 108):

As a demonstration, here is an implementation using [`threeparttable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
        \midrule
                 &     \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text}     \\
        Row 1    & 1        & 0.67    & 0.55       & 0.41    \\
        Row 2    & 2        & 0.02    & 0.01       & 0.39    \\
        Row 3    & 3        & 0.15    & 0.33       & 0.34    \\
        Row 4    & 4        & 1.00    & 0.76       & 0.54    \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of threeparttable LaTeX package]

Comment: Thanks to your nice answer and for pointing me to booktabgs. Could you/anyone help me on how to get `\midrule` s that do not span the whole table (like `\cline`)?

Comment: I found the solution on my own. It is using `\cmidrule{a-b}` where `a`and `b` are the number of rows spanned (to span a single row use e.g., `\cmidrule{1-1}`.

Answer (score 31):

You can use `{\raggedright insert notes here \par}` after `\end{tabular}` but before `\end{table}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
     \centering
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \hline \hline 
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
        \hline 
                 &     \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text}     \\
        Row 1    & 1        & 0.67    & 0.55       & 0.41    \\
        Row 2    & 2        & 0.02    & 0.01       & 0.39    \\
        Row 3    & 3        & 0.15    & 0.33       & 0.34    \\
        Row 4    & 4        & 1.00    & 0.76       & 0.54    \\
        \hline 
     \end{tabular}
     \vspace{1ex}

     {\raggedright This is where authors provide additional information about the data, including whatever notes are needed. \par}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, notice that the notes will span the whole page, and will not be limited to the width of the table.

Comment: Please note that `\raggedright` doesn't take an argument but is a switch. Correct syntax would be `{\raggedright <Text>\par}`.

Comment: This is the most simplistic answer

Answer (score 13):

You could just add a `\multicolumn{<ncols>}{|p{<width>}|}` for the last row.

Comment: But how do you know what width to put there? That's an important detail that this answer lacks.

Comment: @RobKennedy This is a bit late, but I ended up here looking for how to do this. What worked in my case was to use `\linewidth` for the width, although you could also use something like `\columnwidth` depending on what your formatting is.

Comment: @robkennedy 14 cm seems to work well