# Add keys to table (with picture and code)

Tags: tables, symbols, captions, tabularx, syntax

As you see in the red part of the picture, I would like to add keys to explain what the brackets stand for. I just added this with paint, but is there a way to do this in tex? Also, are there nicer semantics for explaining such keys, e.g. using a `:` or spelling brackets as `brackets`?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
 \centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | c c |}
  \hline
 & Column1 & Column2 \\ \hline
    X   & A (B)     & F                 \\ 
        y           & C     & F [D]     \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
            \caption{Some table}
        \label{tab:table}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Perhaps I fail to see the difficulty in the possible solutions. What is wrong with adding a (multi column) extra row and putting the explanations (legends) there? Also see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12676/add-notes-under-the-table).

Comment: Nothing, I just wasn't using the correct search terms and I'm quite new to tex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are other possibilities (like adding a footnote using `threeparttable` etc), here is a simple way using an extra row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!ht]
 \centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
 \begin{tabular}{ | l | c c |}      \hline
        & Column1 & Column2 \\ \hline
    X   & A (B)   & F                 \\
            y     & C     & F [D]     \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{1.5in}}{\footnotesize (\,) $=$ special case}\\
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{1.5in}}{\footnotesize [\,] $=$ other special case}    
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Some table}
  \label{tab:table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]