# adding notes below the table

Tags: tables

I want to add a note below the table. I referred the following link: [Add notes under the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12676/add-notes-under-the-table). But the code given :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{lllll}
      \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \          \midrule
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text} \            Row 1 & 1 & 0.67 & 0.55 & 0.41 \            Row 2 & 2 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.39 \            Row 3 & 3 & 0.15 & 0.33 & 0.34 \            Row 4 & 4 & 1.00 & 0.76 & 0.54 \          \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

doesn't work(it doesn't compile and gives me 42 errors). I want to achieve a table something like this:

[image]

Comment: the code in this question was copied from an answer that got caught in the [double-backslash tsunami](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7168/579).  please don't try to correct it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.25\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.15\linewidth}}
%\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{C|}{*{2}{L|}}}\hline
Course &  Institution/ School  & Board/University  &  Years of  passing  & Aggregate  \\ \hline 
B.Tech.,  Electrical  \&  Electronics 
Engineering & Pondicherry  Engineering College  Puducherry & Pondicherry  University& 2010  pursuing & $8.42^\star$ \\     \hline
Higher  secondary  &  St.Joseph Of Cluny  H.S.S.  Punducherry & TamiNadu Board of 
Higher Secondary  Education & 2006  & 93.375\% \\   \hline         
Matriculation  &  St.Joseph Of  Cluny  H.S.S.   Punducherry & TamiNadu Board of 
Secondary Education &2004 & 92.456\% \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item  \textbf{${}^\star$ Cumulative grade point average up to $6^{th}$ semester}.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
%\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need standalone and normal tabular, without a table, but with text right below the tabular environment (`\end{tabular} \\ Brief explanation/legend here`). Is this simply impossible using standalone? (In which case I should stop trying).

Answer (score 2):

You have tried using a single backslash to start a new row, but that is wrong, it should be  a double backslash, `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{lllll}
      \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\  \midrule
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text} \\
        Row 1 & 1 & 0.67 & 0.55 & 0.41 \\
        Row 2 & 2 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.39 \\
        Row 3 & 3 & 0.15 & 0.33 & 0.34 \\           
        Row 4 & 4 & 1.00 & 0.76 & 0.54 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That was, for some reason, also the case in the original post by Jopesh Wright. I fixed the code over there.