# Table notes at the bottom

Tags: tables

I need a table to be displayed as below
[image]

The code for the table that I have written is :

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin {table}[htbp]
\label{table:3.6}
 \caption{Phase control word}
\centering\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{|@{}*{18}{c|}@{}}
\hline
{} & {} & \multicolumn{16}{c}{Phase Control Word(Binary)}\\ 
\hline
frequency & Phase  & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit &      Bit & Bit & Bit 4 & Bit 3 & Bit 2 & Bit 1 & Bit 0\\
{} & Control Word & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3  & 2 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
48000 & 16384 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\

1000 & 341 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\

8000 & 2731 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\

14000 & 4779 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\

21000 & 7168 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\

\hline
\multicolumn{18}{l}{%
  \begin{minipage}{6.5cm}%
 Note: [By University Requirement, no text should be allowed here in this landscape table/picture page. DON''T USE sidewaystable from rotating package, it cannot align landscape title to the left binding side.].%
  \end{minipage}%
}\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is how my output looks like-
[image]

I am missing the right margin in the right most column header and the 2nd line of table note is not center aligned. Please help me with this

Comment: The standard way to do this is to use the `threeparttable` package. See [Add notes under the table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12676/2693) (which is probably a duplicate.)

Comment: To have the missing rule: `\multicolumn{16}{c|}{Phase Control Word(Binary)}`. To have the note below, follow Alan Munn's link and use there `\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item\relax\centering [By University Requirement, no text should be allowed here in this landscape table/picture page. DON''T USE sidewaystable from rotating package, it cannot align landscape title to the left binding side.].
\end{tablenotes}`

Comment: Also, inside floats `\label` must go **after** `\caption`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array} % fixes the corners
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{table}{5}
\begin{table}[htbp] % only use those if needed.
    \caption{Phase control word}\label{table:3.6} % label after caption!
    \centering\footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{2.1pt}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{18}{c|}@{}}
        \hline
         &  & \multicolumn{16}{c|}{Phase Control Word(Binary)}\\ 
        \hline
        Frequ. & Phase  & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit\\
         & Control Word & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3  & 2 & 1 & 0\\        \hline
        48000 & 16384 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\         
        1000 & 341 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\        
        8000 & 2731 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\       
        14000 & 4779 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\      
        21000 & 7168 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\      
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
     \centering [By University Requirement, no text should be allowed here in this landscape table/picture page. DON'T USE sidewaystable from rotating package, it cannot align landscape title to the left binding side.]. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can save some more space by deleting those vertical lines:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array} % fixes the corners
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{table}{5}
\begin{table}[htbp] % only use those if needed.
    \caption[Phase control word]{Phase Control Word(Binary)}\label{table:3.6} % label after caption!
    \centering\footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{2.39pt}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=5.0,group-four-digits]*{17}{c}@{}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Frequ.} & Phase  & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit & Bit\\
         & Control Word & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3  & 2 & 1 & 0\\        \midrule
        48000 & 16384 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\         
        1000 & 341 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\        
        8000 & 2731 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\       
        14000 & 4779 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\      
        21000 & 7168 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\      
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
     \centering [By University Requirement, no text should be allowed here in this landscape table/picture page. DON'T USE sidewaystable from rotating package, it cannot align landscape title to the left binding side.]. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]