# Need to add footnote under the table

Tags: tables, biblatex, footnotes

I would like to add note directly under the table, not at end of page. I looked at this exmple but it does not work for me.

[Add notes under the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12676/add-notes-under-the-table)

Thanks

Comment: Here, maybe.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption/99289#99289 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption/99293#99293

Comment: You looked at that page, but it has three possible solutions.  Which ones don't work for you?  In what way do they fail?  It's impossible to help you without this information.  The `threeparttable` solution, for example, works fine for me.  What goes wrong when you try it?

Comment: Statements such as "it does not work for me" are much to unspecific and therefore not helfpul. To begin with, please tell us exactly what "it" is. Telling us what "doesn't work" may mean for your specific table would also be most welcome.

Comment: You can put the table and the footnote inside a minipage. (Don't forget the usage of \footnotemark and \footnotetext)

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could show us not only what you tried so far in an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), but also if you could explain what exactly you would like to see in more detail. Since you seem to be aware of possible solutions, it would be great if you could tell us why and how they didn't work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add notes under the table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12676/add-notes-under-the-table)