# I don't like my table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to include a small table into my LaTeX. I would like it to be centered on the page.

My problem is that my fourth column has huge spaces to the right and to the left, I assume to compensate for the text I have written in the note underneath the table. Could you please help me shrink the size of my table, so it's not so obnoxious?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 

% Some Tables packages 
\usepackage{tabularx,dcolumn,ragged2e,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Migration of Non-EU-State citizens from 2010 to 2016}
  \label{tab:one}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    Year & Immigration & Emigration & Net Migration\\
    \midrule
    2010 & 232,007 & 138,404 & 93,603 \\
    2011 & 265,728 & 140,665 & 125,063 \\
    2012 & 305,595 & 141,490 & 164,105 \\
    2013 & 362,984 & 146,040 & 216,944 \\
    2014 & 518,802 & 181,381 & 337,421 \\
    2015 & 1,125,419 & 265,603 & 859,816 \\
    2016 & 673,217 & 324,333 & 348,884 \\   
    \midrule[0.8pt]
    \multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{\RaggedRight %
    See: Bundesamt f\"{u}r Migration und Fl\"{u}chtlinge. Forschungszentrum Migration, Integration und Asyl. \textit{Wanderungsmonitoring: Erwerbsmigration nach Deutschland. Bericht f\"{u}r das Jahr 2016}. Table 1.
    }
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how I would do it:

[image: table]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 

% Some Tables packages 
\usepackage{tabularx,dcolumn,ragged2e,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\captionsetup[table]{font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Migration of Non-EU-State citizens from 2010 to 2016}
  \label{tab:one}
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{cS[group-separator={,},input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.},table-format=7.0]S[group-separator={,},input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.},table-format=7.0]S[group-separator={,},input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.},table-format=7.0]}
    \toprule
    Year & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Immigration} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Emigration} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Net Migration}\\
    \midrule
    2010 & 232,007 & 138,404 & 93,603 \\
    2011 & 265,728 & 140,665 & 125,063 \\
    2012 & 305,595 & 141,490 & 164,105 \\
    2013 & 362,984 & 146,040 & 216,944 \\
    2014 & 518,802 & 181,381 & 337,421 \\
    2015 & 1,125,419 & 265,603 & 859,816 \\
    2016 & 673,217 & 324,333 & 348,884 \\   
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}\\[.5\baselineskip]
  \parbox{.56\textwidth}{\RaggedRight See: Bundesamt f\"{u}r Migration und Fl\"{u}chtlinge. Forschungszentrum Migration, Integration und Asyl. \textit{Wanderungsmonitoring: Erwerbsmigration nach Deutschland. Bericht f\"{u}r das Jahr 2016}.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this. Except, I would prefer, perhaps, to have the "Table 1: blah blah" at the same size as the table text. To do this, could I simply move up "\footnotesize" to before the "\caption"?

Comment: @Zatchet09 I've improved the whole thing a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Without extra packages, you can do it like this. I used `babel`, but it's not really required, provided you use `\raggedright` for the note, as it won't introduce wrong hyphenation for German.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx, caption}

\captionsetup[table]{font=footnotesize}

\newsavebox{\tabularbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Migration of Non-EU-State citizens from 2010 to 2016}
\label{tab:one}
\footnotesize

\sisetup{table-format=7.0}

\sbox{\tabularbox}{%
  \begin{tabular}{cSSS}
  \toprule
  Year & {Immigration} & {Emigration} & {Net Migration}\\
  \midrule
  2010 &  232007 & 138404 &  93603 \\
  2011 &  265728 & 140665 & 125063 \\
  2012 &  305595 & 141490 & 164105 \\
  2013 &  362984 & 146040 & 216944 \\
  2014 &  518802 & 181381 & 337421 \\
  2015 & 1125419 & 265603 & 859816 \\
  2016 &  673217 & 324333 & 348884 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
\begin{minipage}{\wd\tabularbox}
  \usebox{\tabularbox}

  \medskip

  \raggedright
  \begin{otherlanguage*}{ngerman}
  See: Bundesamt f\"{u}r Migration und Fl\"{u}chtlinge. 
  Forschungszentrum Migration, Integration und Asyl.
  \textit{Wanderungsmonitoring: Erwerbsmigration nach
  Deutschland. Bericht f\"{u}r das Jahr 2016}
  \end{otherlanguage*}
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that numbers should not be input with the comma for separating thousands. They can be inserted, if preferred, in options to `sisetup` (see the manual of `siunitx` for information).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An easier alternative to write notes under the table is to use the `threeparttable` package. See the answer to this question [Add notes under the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12676/add-notes-under-the-table). Using it you don't have to manually set the width of the notes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e,siunitx, caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\captionsetup[table]{font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Migration of Non-EU-State citizens from 2010 to 2016}
\label{tab:one}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{cSSS}
\toprule
Year & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Immigration} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Emigration} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Net Migration}\\
\midrule
2010 & 232,007 & 138,404 & 93,603 \\
2011 & 265,728 & 140,665 & 125,063 \\
2012 & 305,595 & 141,490 & 164,105 \\
2013 & 362,984 & 146,040 & 216,944 \\
2014 & 518,802 & 181,381 & 337,421 \\
2015 & 1125,419 & 265,603 & 859,816 \\
2016 & 673,217 & 324,333 & 348,884 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para]
{\RaggedRight
See: Bundesamt f\"{u}r Migration und Fl\"{u}chtlinge. Forschungszentrum Migration, Integration und Asyl. \textit{Wanderungsmonitoring: Erwerbsmigration nach Deutschland. Bericht f\"{u}r das Jahr 2016}
}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is more of a commentary than anything else. You should elaborate on the answer (making it complete with some code) or convert it into a comment.

Comment: Ok. I've added the code to my answer.

Comment: `\centering` should go before `\begin{threeparttable}`; remove the `flushleft` option and use `\begin{tablenotes}[para]`, without `\item`. Probably `\raggedright` is better as the text is in German and the hyphenation allowed by `\RaggedRight` can be wrong for the language.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However if I change `\RaggedRight` to `\raggedright` the text will be justified.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 

% Some Tables packages 
\usepackage{tabularx,dcolumn,ragged2e,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Migration of Non-EU-State citizens from 2010 to 2016}
  \label{tab:one}
  \footnotesize
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{cccc}
    \toprule
    Year & Immigration & Emigration & Net Migration\\
    \midrule
    2010 & 232,007 & 138,404 & 93,603 \\
    2011 & 265,728 & 140,665 & 125,063 \\
    2012 & 305,595 & 141,490 & 164,105 \\
    2013 & 362,984 & 146,040 & 216,944 \\
    2014 & 518,802 & 181,381 & 337,421 \\
    2015 & 1,125,419 & 265,603 & 859,816 \\
    2016 & 673,217 & 324,333 & 348,884 \\   
    \midrule[0.8pt]
    \multicolumn{4}{X}{\RaggedRight %
    See: Bundesamt f\"{u}r Migration und Fl\"{u}chtlinge. Forschungszentrum Migration, Integration und Asyl. \textit{Wanderungsmonitoring: Erwerbsmigration nach Deutschland. Bericht f\"{u}r das Jahr 2016}. Table 1.
    }
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have as well included the `caption` package to globally set the font size of all captions to `footnotesize`.

Comment: The caption package was already included. And you should definitely not use `tabularx` if you do not have a `X` column.

Comment: @ TeXnician: In this case I used the `X` column for the multicolumn at the bottom of the table. For me this has worked well every time I used this.

Comment: Well, at least it is not the intended and recommended use.