# problems with caption in LaTeX

Tags: tables, captions

The `\caption` command in the end posts a caption that says "Table 2: (my text)", even though it is only my FIRST table. I want it to say "Table 1". How?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Summary statistics of key variables}
\label{Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
Variable & Obs. & Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\ \midrule
Self-Reported Health & 55,332 & 0.593 & 0.275 & 0 & 1 \\
High blood pressure* & 55,325 & 0.451 & 0.498 & 0 & 1 \\
Diabetes* & 55,319 & 0.143 & 0.350 & 0 & 1 \\
Cancer* & 55,271 & 0.093 & 0.291 & 0 & 1 \\
Lung problems* & 55,328 & 0.064 & 0.245 & 0 & 1 \\
Hearth Problems* & 55,311 & 0.155 & 0.362 & 0 & 1 \\
Stroke (ever)* & 55,333 & 0.041 & 0.199 & 0 & 1 \\
Psychological problems* & 55,325 & 0.107 & 0.309 & 0 & 1 \\
Arthritis* & 55,319 & 0.459 & 0.499 & 0 & 1 \\
Obese* & 54,812 & 0,295 & 0,456 & 0 & 1 \\
Main health index & 54,617 & 0.814 & 0.095 & 0.362 & 0.930 \\
\midrule
Male* & 81,520 & 0.484 & 0.500 & 0 & 1 \\
Age (years) & 55,352 & 60.9 & 6.22 & 50 & 80 \\
Black* & 81,520 & 0.151 & 0.358 & 0 & 1 \\
Hispanic* & 81,520 & 0.088 & 0.284 & 0 & 1 \\
Married/Partnered* & 55,312 & 0.724 & 0.447 & 0 & 1 \\
log(Assets) & 55,352 & 11.1 & 3.32 & 0 & 18.3 \\
log(Debt) & 55,352 & 3.06 & 4.11 & 0 & 14.7 \\
Age of mother & 55,036 & 75.4 & 13.6 & 16 & 110 \\
Age of father & 55,091 & 71.5 & 14.1 & 12 & 116 \\
Father alive* & 55,104 & 0.123 & 0.328 & 0 & 1 \\
Mother alive* & 55,046 & 0.308 & 0.461 & 0 & 1 \\
\bottomrule
Vigorous activity +2 times a week & 55,185 & 0.342 & 0.475 & 0 & 1 \\
Smokes currently & 55,146 & 0.188 & 0.391 & 0 & 1 \\
Self-reported prob(working past age 62) (\%) & 29,790 & 47.1 & 39.9 & 0 & 100 \\
Self-reported prob(working past age 65) (\%) & 33,725 & 27.0 & 34.5 & 0 & 100


\end{tabular}
\caption{*dummy variable: estimates refer not to averages but to sample proportions}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

So my document displays "Table 2: *dummy variables..." and I want "Table 1: *dummy variables"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You have two captions.

Comment: Btw +1 for using `booktabs` and `@{}` for customizing tables.

Comment: I see, then how do I add like a footnote to my tables? Not really a footnote more like just some text RIGHT under the table where I for instance explain what *, ** and *** mean.

Comment: Read here: [Add notes under the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12676/add-notes-under-the-table)

Comment: \documentclass[11pt]{article}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Summary statistics of key variables}
\label{Table 1}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}\hline
first table contents
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\nopagebreak
\begin{table}
 \caption{*dummy variable: estimate& 1 \\
Hispanic* & 81,520 & 0.088 & 0.284 & 0 & 1 \\
Married/Partnered* & 55,312 & 0.724 s refer not to averages but to sample proportions}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}\hline

second table contents

\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}