# LaTeX table capabilities

Tags: tables

This might be a proper question for community wiki.

How can various text processor (like Word or Writer) table capabilities be achieved using LaTeX? For example, can I achieve:

- multicolumns and multirows (yes, with `multirow` package)
- [merge cells operation spanning multiple rows and columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/latex-table-capabilities/13026#13026), respecting borders. Illustrated with figure below:

[image: Row and column spanning]

- equal column distribution (yes, with appropriate column types and manually inputting column widths, or `tabularx` package)
- equal rows distribution (?)
- [changing text direction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/latex-table-capabilities/12942#12942) (yes, does not depend on table enviroment?)
- cell/row shading (yes, with `colorx` package)
- [using borders and lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/latex-table-capabilities/13287#13287)
- setting borders of each cell individually (?)
- [aligning cell contents inside a cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/latex-table-capabilities/13283#13283) in all 9 directions (vertical, horizontal and centering)
- etc.

Comment: in agreement with your suggestion I converted it to community wiki. Using one separate comprehensive answer for elaborating each task together with an example may be a good idea. Within answers, it would be good to provide also internal links to good answers to questions about the specific task.

Comment: I want to recommend this page as well: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables
 I go there very often to check up on how to do things related to tables...

Answer (score 12):

## Merge cells operation spanning multiple rows and columns, respecting borders.

Can be done using a `\multirow` (`multirow` package) inside a `\multicolumn`.
The borders are drawn using `\hline` or `\cline`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                                                                            \hline
   Text A                        &  Text B                       & Test C \\\hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Longer Text, etc. etc.}} & Test F \\\cline{3-3}
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                                        & Test G \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: Result]

Comment: Excellent! That is the kind of an answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 9):

I find this link very helpful: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/#

Comment: I can not under stand why this answer is not on the top !!

Answer (score 8):

## Changing text direction

This can be done using the `\rotatebox` macro of `graphicx`.
The syntax is:

```
\rotatebox[origin=<O>]{<angle in degree>}{<Text>}
```

The origin on which the text is rotated can be:
  `l` (left),
  `r` (right),
  `c` (center)
and
  `t` (top),
  `b` (bottom),
  `B` (baseline).

For example `rt` is the right top corner. Default is `lB`.

### Example Code:

```
\documentclass[convert={png,density=150}]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Draw tight framebox around cell text
\newcommand*{\x}[1]{{%
    \fboxsep=0pt
    \fboxrule=.1pt
    \fbox{\strut#1}%
}}
\let\x\empty
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
  \toprule
    \rlap{\rule{35em}{.1pt}}% Marker only
    Normal 
  &  \rotatebox{90}{90 up}origin
  &  \rotatebox{180}{Up side down, deep}
  &  \rotatebox{270}{270 down}
  &  \rotatebox{45}{45 degrees up}
  &  \rotatebox[origin=rB]{-45}{135 degrees up}
  \\\midrule
    \rlap{\rule{35em}{.1pt}}% Marker only
    Normal
  &  \rotatebox[origin=rB]{90}{90 down}
  &  \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{Up side down, baseline}
  &  \rotatebox[origin=rB]{270}{270 up}
  &  \rotatebox{-45}{45 degrees down}
  &  \rotatebox[origin=rB]{45}{135 degrees down}
  \\\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 8):

### Alignment within table cells

**Horizontal Alignment:** use the column types `l`, `c`, `r`, and `p` to align left, centered, right, and full, respectively. An example, taken from my [blog](http://texblog.net/latex-beginners-guide/examples/chapter-5#horizontal-alignment), resp. book:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|p{1.7cm}|}
  \hline
  left & centered & right & a fully justified paragraph cell\\
  \hline
  l & c & r & p\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: horizonal alignment]

**Vertical Alignment:** use the [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) package and column types `p`, `m`, and `b` to align top, centered, and bottom, respectively. An example, taken from my [blog](http://texblog.net/latex-beginners-guide/examples/chapter-5#vertical-alignment), resp. book:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{1.2cm}m{1.2cm}b{1.2cm}@{}}
  \hline
  baseline & aligned at the top& aligned at the middle
    & aligned at the bottom\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: vertical alignment]

Answer (score 7):

### Horizontal lines in tables

The `booktabs` package provides commands for

- **full-width lines:** they can be done bye `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`. All accept an optional argument for the thickness, which can be globally adjusted by modifying the lengths `\heavyrulewidth` (`\toprule`, `\bottomrule`) and `\lightrulewidth` (`\midrule`), respectively.
- **partial lines:** they can be drawn by `\cmidrule`:

  `\cmidrule[width](trim){m–n}`

Here's an example for illustration, also taken from my [blog](http://texblog.net/latex-beginners-guide/examples/chapter-5#merging), resp. book:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*3l@{}}
  \toprule[1.5pt]
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Input}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\head{Output}}\\
  \head{Command} & \head{Declaration} & \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
  \verb|\textrm| & \verb|\rmfamily| & \rmfamily Example text\\
  \verb|\textsf| & \verb|\sffamily| & \sffamily Example text\\
  \verb|\texttt| & \verb|\ttfamily| & \ttfamily Example text\\
  \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

While I can see that some features are easier to access in WYSIWYG DTP software than in LaTeX, some features are best avoided to achieve a professional table design. See the discussion on [table formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12213/formatting-table/12217#12217) where I provide a before-and-after example that highlights the problem of a Word-like layout. The [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) design is required reading for professional table layout in LaTeX.

Things that I wish would be easier in LaTeX is table design simply based on background colors but without relying on lines. Any recommendations?

Comment: I believe most users here appreciate beautiful documents, and that is one of the reasons we are using TeX or friends. "Professional table design" does not solve all problems or requirements, and the example gives only the most "natural" applications.

Comment: @ipavlic I'm sorry if my answer was misleading. I didn't want to suggest that using the `booktabs` package will lead to the best result in all cases. I do like it because it comes with a design philosophy. Clearly there are good designs that cannot be achieved with it and that is why we need other packages as well. However, I still believe that some coherent package for a particular style is most useful to achieve a consistent design. Features available in Word et al. need some design experience, too, to put them to good use and they do not lead to good design automatically.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. Some use cases however demand a more low-level approach. I am particularly interested in how to distribute rows evenly.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [Tabsatz](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/german/tabsatz/) documentation.  It is in German, but the Latex code is very clear

Comment: I like the examples and principles demonstrated in that document. Maybe it is time for a community wiki that collects best practices for typesetting tables.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [Tabu](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/tabu.html) package documentation. It introduces some new capacities to tabulars.

Comment: Telling from the documentation, an interesting and powerful package!