# Complex Table Layout

Tags: tables, formatting, positioning

I'm trying to display a fairly complex table using Latex. Here is what I want it to look like (formatting, alignment, borders, columnspan, and rowspan). I would also like the columns to be fixed width (or at least have all the columns after the first one be the same width). Here is what I want it to look like:

[image: Table-Goal]

Here is what I have so far:

[image: Table-Current]

And here is the code for it:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centerline{
{\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{1in}|p{.5in}|p{.5in}|p{.5in}|p{.5in}|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{A}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{B}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{C}} \\
& Wrap Text 1 & Wrap Text 2 & Wrap Text 1 & Wrap Text 2 \\
\hline
\textbf{Heading 1}  &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 \\
\hline
\textbf{Heading 2}  &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 \\
\hline
\textbf{Heading 3}  &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 \\
\hline
\textbf{Total}      &  6 &  9 & 12 & 15 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
}
\caption{Still Not Working}
\end{figure}
```

I'm pretty stuck at this point. Whenever I fix one issue it seems to make it impossible to fix the others. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might check Martin Scharrer's reply on [LaTeX table capabilities](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/latex-table-capabilities) (Merge cells operation spanning multiple rows and columns, respecting borders)

Comment: @ipavlic: Thanks for adding the link. I was planning to add it by myself after seeing the question title. I took the liberty to change the displayed link URL to the link title (see [Can we have some linking etiquette and guidelines?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489/can-we-have-some-linking-etiquette-and-guidelines) on meta).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replicating your image:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centerline{
    {\small
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1in}|p{.5in}|p{.5in}|p{.5in}|p{.5in}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{A}} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{B}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{C}} \\
        & 
        \multicolumn{1}{p{1in}}{Wrap Text 1} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{p{1in}}{Wrap Text 2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{1in}}{Wrap Text 1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{p{1in}|}{Wrap Text 1}  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Heading 1}  &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Heading 2}  &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Heading 3}  &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Total}      &  6 &  9 & 12 & 15 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    }
    \caption{Working, but with many rules}
\end{figure}
```

The clue is to check the |'s in the `multicolumn` format specifiers carefully, to fix any missing rules.

However, I prefer the layout below, it contains no vertical rules, and less horizontal rules. In general, I find it to be preferable to use as few rules as possible in tables. The example uses the `booktabs` package, for better-looking rules in tables.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centerline{
    {\small
    \begin{tabular}{p{1in}rrrr}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries{B}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries{C}} \\
        \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
        \bfseries{A}
        & \multicolumn{1}{p{1in}}{Wrap Text 1}
        & \multicolumn{1}{p{1in}}{Wrap Text 2}
        & \multicolumn{1}{p{1in}}{Wrap Text 1}
        & \multicolumn{1}{p{1in}}{Wrap Text 2}  \\ \midrule
        \textbf{Heading 1}  &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 \\
        \textbf{Heading 2}  &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 \\
        \textbf{Heading 3}  &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 \\
        \textbf{Total}      &  6 &  9 & 12 & 15 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }
    }
    \caption{Working, with less rules}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why use a `figure` environment for a table? Edit: Sorry, I see that the OP has used this as well.

Comment: That's great. Thanks! I notice, however, that the "Wrap Text 1/2" column headers are still aligned right. How would one change their alignment (say, to centered)?

Comment: Since it's in a p-column, you can just use centering.