# How to merge columns in a table?

Tags: tables

I have this table, but wanted to format the first row. I like to match the two columns of first row, and last two columns of the same first row. Any suggestion on how to do that?

```
\begin{table}[!h] 
\caption{Comparison of percentages.}
\begin{tabular}{lclclclclc}
\hline
\hline 
Mode &  Var  &  Cum\\
\hline
{}       & EF   & CHF    & EF2   & CHF2\\
1   &  17.5 & 19.1   & 17.5  & 19.1\\
2   &  11.8 & 12.7   & 29.3  &  31.9\\
3   &  6.6  &  5.6         & 35.9    &  37.4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Have a look at [LaTeX table capabilities](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/latex-table-capabilities), there are examples with code, output and explanation.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

This can be done using [`\multicolumn`](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/tables/#Multicolumn):

```
\multicolumn{<no of columns>}{<column alignment>}{<content>}
```

As an example, with some improvements using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{4pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Comparison of percentages.}
\begin{tabular}{*5c}
\toprule
Mode &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Var} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Cum}\\
\midrule
{}   & EF   & CHF    & EF2   & CHF2\\
1   &  17.5 & 19.1   & 17.5  & 19.1\\
2   &  11.8 & 12.7   & 29.3  & 31.9\\
3   &  6.6  &  5.6   & 35.9  & 37.4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table with merged cells]

Comment: @ Stefan Kottwitz:  Thank you very much! This is amazing! Is it possible to shift the Mode back to first column and Var on top of 2nd/3rd columns?

Comment: @BrettHarry: no problem, just apply `\multicolumn` to `Var` instead, I modified the example.

Comment: @BrettHarry [Mori's paper](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf) and [booktabs documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) can help you design good tables.

Comment: Is it also possible to add a linebreak to a `\multicolumn`?

Comment: If you have vertical lines in your table, you need to use `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{text}` (not that it's `c|` instead of just `c`) ([Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133805/195804)).

Answer (score 47):

```
\multicolumn{<no of columns>}{<column type>}{<stuff>}
```

there are a lot of examples if you search for this topic

Comment: I wish this answer was merged into the accepted one as a small prefix

Comment: merging accomplished

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Comparison of percentages.}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {crrrr},
  cell{1}{2,4} = {c=2}{c}, % multicolumn (column number=2, center alignment)
}
\hline[2pt]
  Mode &   Var &      &  Cum &      \\
\hline[1pt]
       &    EF &  CHF &  EF2 & CHF2 \\
\cline{2-5}
    1  &  17.5 & 19.1 & 17.5 & 19.1 \\
    2  &  11.8 & 12.7 & 29.3 & 31.9 \\
    3  &   6.6 &  5.6 & 35.9 & 37.4 \\
\hline[2pt]
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Comparison of percentages.}
\begin{booktabs}{
  colspec = {crrrr},
  cell{1}{2,4} = {c=2}{c}, % multicolumn (column number=2, center alignment)
}
\toprule
  Mode &   Var &      &  Cum &      \\
\midrule
       &    EF &  CHF &  EF2 & CHF2 \\
\cmidrule[lr]{2-3}\cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
    1  &  17.5 & 19.1 & 17.5 & 19.1 \\
    2  &  11.8 & 12.7 & 29.3 & 31.9 \\
    3  &   6.6 &  5.6 & 35.9 & 37.4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{booktabs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]