# How to make table with divided column

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to merge columns in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22856/how-to-merge-columns-in-a-table)

[image]

How can I make a table of the type above? I am writing a seminar report using the `report` class.

Comment: Oh, and for the top left cell you're after `multirow`, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35126/combine-4-cells-in-a-table

Answer (score 5):

This is just a quick answer to your question. I will update it if the code is too vague.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % Uncomment to get better display
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{UVLO START} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{MAXIMUM DUTY CYCLE}\\ 
\hhline{~--}
 & $< 50\%$&$< 50\%$ \\\hline
8.5V&  UC3845 & UC3845\\ \hline
16V &  UC3845 & UC3845\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]

If you add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` above `\begin{tabular}` you will get a better display. See below:

[image]

Comment: wen i build this code it shows package need to be installed from random package repository...then i selected install from net which again ask to select a cuntry...which country should i select??

Comment: Choose the one closest to you. I suppose it does not matter just probably the speed at which you download will vary depending on the server.