Reflowing a "narrow" table in multiple columns (side by side) on page, preserving headers?
I haven't been able to find an answer I like on this, so I thought it is worth asking again. LaTeX csvreader/longtable: Put long narrow table multiple times on page is related, however it suggests manually wrapping rows of the table in minipage, which is what I would like to avoid.
Anyways, I have some data that forms a "narrow" table (only three columns), which is usually typeset as a single long table, which in my actual use case would stretch over multiple pages. Here is an MWE:
%example based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193863
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}%Just for introducing dummy text.

\newcommand*{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102792
\newcommand*{\theadl}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries #1}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133804

\title{Some data example}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]%dummy text
\begin{table}[h]
    \small
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|r}
    \hline
    \theadl{Data A} & \theadl{Data B} & \thead{Data C}\\
    \hline
    10 & 100 & 200 \\
    11 & 101 & 201 \\
    12 & 102 & 202 \\
    13 & 103 & 203 \\
    14 & 104 & 204 \\
    15 & 105 & 205 \\
    16 & 106 & 206 \\
    17 & 107 & 207 \\
    18 & 108 & 208 \\
    19 & 109 & 209 \\
    20 & 110 & 220 \\
    21 & 111 & 221 \\
    22 & 112 & 222 \\
    23 & 113 & 223 \\
    24 & 114 & 224 \\
    25 & 115 & 225 \\
    26 & 116 & 226 \\
    27 & 117 & 227 \\
    28 & 118 & 228 \\
    29 & 119 & 229 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This is a table with data}
\end{table}

Well, that was the data, folks ...

\end{document}

This produces the following page:

What I would like, is:

to not change the data entry as in MWE, and so keep the table header row entered only once
find some code/package that will allow me to enter how many page columns I want the table to be split in
Otherwise keep the original setup of document as single-column page

So, for instance, if I enter I want the table reflowed in 2 page columns, then I'd get an output like this (edited in photo software, so not extremely precise; though I'd probably like a way to reduce the horizontal space between the two tables, the below edit shows them aligned with paragraph width; and a way to specify "I want the two columns of tables to be of equal height" vs "I want the first column to have as many rows as possible until end of page, then reflow into table of second column"):

Is there anything out there that could be used for something like this?

Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27088/? The first answer there assumes a different workflow. The second doesn't but may not work without being updated. But one or other might help you decide on a strategy. I think there are more recent Q&As, but I'm not finding them right now.

Many thanks, @cfr - the pgfplotstable approach in the answers at the link you posted looks like something I could use; good to have learned about it!
