# How would I make a table like this?

Tags: tables

[image]

Getting the line that splits down the variables column is giving me trouble.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can make the variables-cell span two columns with `\multicolumn`, see e.g. [How to merge columns in a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22861)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does 'like this' mean 'too minute to see anything'? Or is it the way Firefox is rendering it? I can't even see it is a table! It looks like a short line (emdash?) with two tiny dots below.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to split the colums rather than merging the headline cell:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Variables} &  Statement & Inverse & Converse & Contrapositive\\
\midrule
\textit{p} & \textit{q} & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.