# How to insert a multicolumn among columns?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to create a table in latex in which I have a multicolumn among columns.
something like the following:

[image]

How can I create it?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22856/how-to-merge-columns-in-a-table

Comment: What did you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package multirow (with the command `\multirow{nb of rows}{*}{text}`) and the command `\multicolumn{nb of columns}{alignment}{text}`. The following code make use of this :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{  } & \multirow{2}{*}{  } &\multicolumn{2}{r|}{  } & \multirow{2}{*}{  }\\\cline{3-4}
&    &    &   &\\\hline
&    &    &   &\\\hline
&    &    &   &\\\hline
&    &    &   &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: output]

Comment: The table works good but I want it at the center of my page, and when I use the `\begin{center}` it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3482383 In `article` class it works for me with `\begin{center}`. However, it is usually good to put `tabular` environments inside `table` environments (as it is often recommended to put a caption below you table). So I'm not sure what doesn't work for you, but first check what class you are using (I put my answer in `standalone`, as it shows only what was needed here: the tabular. Sorry if it was that that got your error).

Comment: @user3482383 I realize you might mean the vertical centre of the page. In that case I recommend you to read the second answer to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/vertically-center-text-on-a-page