# Creating a table

Tags: tables

I am puzzled how to create in LaTeX the following table

[image]

I have spent much searching internet and books about latex but I cannot find something relevant.
My problem is how to include the first row which is centered and has two columns as you see and also the last row.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, you are looking for `multicolumn` and the `booktabs` package.

Comment: See [How to merge columns in a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22861) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Include the package `multirow`:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
```

And use it in your table like so:

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ Field variables }
```

The field will now span across 2 cells, the text will be centered, the content will be 'Field variables'.

Comment: package `multirow`?

Comment: As Johannes says, you don't need `multirow` to use `\multicolumn`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! @friday13th: You mentioned the structure `\multicolumn{2}{c}{ Field variables }` . Where should I type "Field equations"?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}cp{1.75cm}p{3cm}p{1.75cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Field variables} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Field equations}\\
\midrule
Name & Symbol & Number of Unknowns & Name & Number of equations \\
\midrule
Displacement (vector) & \textbf{u} & 3 & Conservation of Linear Momentum & 3 (3.2.9) \\
Strain (second-order symmetric tensor) & $\varepsilon$ & 6 & Kinematics & 6 (3.2.4) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: Following Johanne_B and Barbara Beeton suggestions, better aligning and `cmidrules` are introduced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} % for \newcolumntype

\newcolumntype{v}[1]{%
    >{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{v{3.5cm}cv{1.75cm}v{3cm}v{1.75cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Field variables} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Field equations}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
Name & Symbol & Number of Unknowns & Name & Number of equations \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-4}\cmidrule(l){5-5}
Displacement (vector) & \textbf{u} & 3 & Conservation of Linear Momentum & 3 (3.2.9) \\
Strain (second-order symmetric tensor) & $\varepsilon$ & 6 & Kinematics & 6 (3.2.4) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use two `cmidrule`s instead of the `midrules`

Comment: @Ignasi I can "vote" for your answer! But it looks great! Thanks!

Comment: oh, please make the multi-line (paragraph) entries ragged right.  the spacing is terrible otherwise!

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know, but I never remember how to do it and I didn't have time to search for it. I'll do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the replies I got here is the table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}cp{1.75cm}p{3cm}p{1.75cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Field variables} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Field equations}\\
\midrule
Name & Symbol & Number of Unknowns & Name & Number of equations \\
\midrule
Displacement (vector) & $\textbf{u}$ & 3 & Conservation of Linear Momentum & 3 (3.2.9) \\
Strain (second-order symmetric tensor) & $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ & 6 & Kinematics & 6 (3.2.4) \\
Stress (second-order symmetric tensor) & $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ & 6 &  &  \\
Density (scalar) & $\rho$ & 1 & Conservation of Mass & 6 (3.2.4) \\
Internal Energy (scalar) & $u$ & 1 &  & 1 (3.2.4) \\
Temperature (scalar) & $T$ & 1 & Conservation of Mass & 6 (3.2.4) \\
Heat Fluc (scalar) &$\bf{q}$ & 3& &\\
\bottomrule
Number of Unknowns:& & 21 & Number of Equations& 11
\end{tabular}
\caption{Unknown field variables and available field equations in continuum mechanics.}
\end{table}
```

However, I want the contents of all the columns to be left-aligned (APART FROM the first row). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that this site doesn't work like a normal forum, so new questions/follow up questions should not be posted as answers to existing questions. I would recommend that you create a new question with the above text.

Comment: That said, you sort of have the answer in that code already: `\multicolumn`. You can have a `\multicolumn` spanning just one column, i.e. `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}`.

Answer (score 0):

As a start point you can try this site http://www.tablesgenerator.com
it will help you to create table online like in excel