# Drawing two specific tables

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have two specific tables that I do not know how to draw these tables? Can someone help me in drawing these tables?[image]

Comment: What are the problems?

Comment: I do not know how can I these tables.

Comment: @Farid this is no free coding service, so show the code you've got so far.

Comment: You can take a look at this [simple introduction](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables), for instance.

Comment: @ Timothy Truckle, I'll do my best and I will inform you the result. Thanks.

Comment: Mostly that's `\multicolumn`, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22856/how-to-merge-columns-in-a-table/22861#22861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
First and last name               & Number ID               & University              & City              & Country              & Your Favorite              & Sign              \\ \hline
                                  &                         &                         &                   &                      &                            &                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Address: The Old Schools, Trinity Lane, Cambridge CB2 1TN UK, Email: admission@cam.ac.uk\\ Tel: +44 (0) 1223 333308\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Number} & First and last name & Number ID                     & University   & City   & Country                       & Your Favorite  & Sign \\ \hline
1                            &                     &                               &              &        &                               &                &      \\ \hline
2                            &                     &                               &              &        &                               &                &      \\ \hline
3                            &                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Email 1:} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Email 2:} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```