# Tables or other ways to achieve complex page layout

Tags: tables, wrap

Posting it as a new question, also related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141924/how-to-typeset-a-complex-layout-like-a-page-of-the-talmud) as well as maybe relevant in [this context of table formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/latex-table-capabilities/142353#142353)...
What about some things that, to my knowledge, no (other) word processor can achieve at all? I am desperately looking for a way to write a table (or what ever way is possible to achieve this layout) in LaTeX that contains 4 columns and 3 rows where the cells 1&2 of the first, cell 1 of the second and cells 1&2 of the third row are merged and 3&4 of the first, cell 4 of the second and cells 3&4 of the third row, too, are merged. the two cells in the middle also should be merged. Is there any way to implement this with any table environment in LaTeX? for a better idea of what I am trying to achieve, here is how it should roughly look like:

[image: table]

Anyone any idea how to achieve this? This is related to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141924/how-to-typeset-a-complex-layout-like-a-page-of-the-talmud), which, too, hasn't lead to an answer yet...

Comment: do you need text to flow automatically between these regions or is it three separate text flows, and does text need to flow on to another page?

Comment: Without a description about the contents of the page you described it seems impossible to help you.

Comment: A "table" is a float (which differs from "figure" only in its caption).  A "tabular" is a table.  (All nomenclature is confusing.  Some are more confusing than others.)

Comment: You can merge cells horizontally using \multicolumn and vertically using \multirow, but not as you described.  You might try 6 columns and only use 4 at a time.  You can put tabulars inside tabulars.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry that I was not very clear about it. Indeed all three boxes contain different texts, not one text flowing through three boxes.
The main text in the middle - on the left &right commentaries. I know this is probably highly unusual & that might be the reason no word processor can do this, yet it has been a very important layout for texts such as the [Talmud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud), for example and the layout is very old, dating back to the [16th century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Bomberg).

Comment: I just discovered the flowframes http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram package, which might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I have often wondered whether it is possible to achieve such a layout with LaTeX, and somehow, I always thought the answer was "no, this is not possible". However, I recently learned that it *is* possible, and surprisingly convenient, with the [`pullquote`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pullquote.dtx) package by [Stephan Lehmke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12850/stephan-lehmke), advertised (for example) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert/70169#70169).

The solution for your desired layout would then look somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pullquote}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{pullquote}{object={\parbox{.4\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}}}
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{pullquote}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```