# How to assign merged cells to the right colunm?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I've been trying to make a table using the \booktabs pagackage and following [this model](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13287) with some tweaks. However, the merged cells end up in the wrong column, namely the first column and not the third as I intend.

I'd appreciate your help! Working example is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*4l@{}}
    \toprule[1.5pt]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\head{Group}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\head{1st round}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{2nt round}}\\
    \head{New Interview Partners} & \head{Follow-Up Interviews} & \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
    Group 1 & 4 & 0 & 4\\
    Group 2 & 5 & 3 & 3\\
    Group 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    Total & 11 & 4 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And here what it looks like when I compile:
[image: table showing merged cells under the wrong column]

And this is a rough sketch of what it should look like (but in booktabs style):
[image: sketch of table as it should look like, namely with last column with merged cells]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please further clarify the desired output? Maybe a sketch would help?

Comment: thanks for your comment, leandriis! Just added a sketch to the original post, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the added sketch. This helped a lot to clarify the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the `&` after `\head{Follow-Up...` and added `& &` in the beginning of this line. Also, I have split up the three words over two rows. Lastly, I have changed the use of `\cmidrule` and added a `\midrule` (as well as corrected the typo in the last column of the first row).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*4l@{}}
    \toprule[1.5pt]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\head{Group}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\head{1st round}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{2nd round}}\\
    \cmidrule(l){3-4}
   & & \head{New Interview } & \head{Follow-Up }  \\
   & & \head{Partners} & \head{Interviews}  \\
    \midrule
    Group 1 & 4 & 0 & 4\\
    Group 2 & 5 & 3 & 3\\
    Group 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    Total & 11 & 4 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! This worked perfectly! Cheers :)

Comment: @deb: You're welcome. If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, didn't know about that! Will upvote as soon as I get more reputation points. For now, marked as accepted answer