# Dealing with Long Table head entries?

Tags: tables

As seen below, my goal is to save some space. For example,

```
                     Applied
                      Model
Logistic 
Model
```

[image]

The code i'm using to generate the table is:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-5pt}
\centering
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{llccc}
\hline
Algorithm & Dataset &  Applied Model (\%) & Definition of data  (\%) & Overall Assumptions (\%)  \\ \hline 
\multirow{3}{*}{Logistic MODEL} & + & 63.6 & 98 &  95.3937  \\ 
 & - & 68.1 & 95.5 & 95.4757   \\
 & - & 100 & 100 & 99.1935 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\label{table:tex-exchange}
\end{table}
```

Comment: In addition to Gonzalo's answer, there are some more suggestions here: [Formatting table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12213/formatting-table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` to override the column specification and then put the header text inside a `\parbox` (I centered the text inside each `\parbox`, but this is, of course, optional); the following modification of your code illustrates this approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand\MyHead[2]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\parbox{#1}{\centering #2}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3pt}
  \centering
  {\scriptsize
  \begin{tabular}{@{}llccc@{}}
    \toprule
    Algorithm & Dataset & \MyHead{1.3cm}{Applied\\ Model (\%)} 
      & \MyHead{1.5cm}{Definition\\ of data  (\%)}
      & \MyHead{2.2cm}{Overall\\ Assumptions (\%)}  \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-4}\cmidrule(l){5-5}
    \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1cm}{Logistic\\ MODEL}} & + & 63.6 & 98 &  95.3937  \\ 
    & $-$ & 68.1 & 95.5 & 95.4757   \\
    & $-$ & 100 & 100 & 99.1935 \\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
  \label{table:tex-exchange}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: another option would be to manually split the header text using several rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3pt}
  \centering
  {\scriptsize
  \begin{tabular}{@{}llccc@{}}
    \toprule
    Algorithm & Dataset & Applied  & Definition & Overall  \\ 
    & & Model (\%) & of data (\%) & Assumptions (\%)  \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-4}\cmidrule(l){5-5}
    \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{1cm}{Logistic\\ MODEL}} & + & 63.6 & 98 &  95.3937  \\ 
    & $-$ & 68.1 & 95.5 & 95.4757   \\
    & $-$ & 100 & 100 & 99.1935 \\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
  \label{table:tex-exchange}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Note that I took the liberty to use some of the features provided by the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package; of course, this suggestion is completely optional.