# Multirow and lines - how to draw line going through selected columns

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable, rules

I was wondering if it is possible to draw line which goes through some columns in table(not all columns). I have a table which looks like that

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{some text }
\label{tab:artificialShapes}
\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Shape} & \multirow{2}{*}{$C^{*}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$C_{0}$} &\multirow{2}{*}{$N$} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Noisless data}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Noisy data}} \\
\hline
& & & & $J_{b}$ & $J_{a}$ & time[s] & $\rho$  & $J_{b}$ & $J_{a}$ & time[s] & $\rho$ \\ \hline

\end{longtable}
```

The problem is that text which is placed in multirow command is crossed by line. Is it possible to prevent a line from going through all columns ?

Comment: You might find the following question useful: [LaTeX table capabilities](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12940/2693) and also [Formatting table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12213/2693). It's generally not a good idea to have vertical lines in tables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

instead of the second `\hline` use `\cline{5-12}`

And by the way: you can write `\begin{longtable}{|*{12}{c|}}` for your tabular definition