# want to make table in latex command

Tags: pdftex, diagrams

to make my cv, to give educational information in a table with box box, I have used this

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (-5,0) grid (4,4);




  \end{tikzpicture}
```

and got [image: nnnn]

but I want to write my university name marks etc etc inside those boxes and I want to make bit wider boxes, I want proper latex commands for such table ..
thank you for helping.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `tabular` environment.

Comment: I have no idea but I hope I am able to express what I want?

Comment: Checkout [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs)
. You probably want something like `\begin{tabular}{  l  l }\toprule
     University & Years \\
     \cmidrule{1-1}
     Stanford University & 1990-1994 \\
     \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}`.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu saaaaaaaaaar

Comment: This is *not* the appropriate way to make a table to represent what you're after.

Comment: :-o :-o then??????????????????????

Comment: @Tojamaru: See [Create a table with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115280/5764) (making this a duplicate, I think).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: I have done it, thank you for your great advise